# Setting zoom controls for Image View

Tags: android

I am new to android, I need to zoom an selected imageview given statically in array defined in my code. 
How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

As I said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405468/android-can-i-use-a-zoom-control-in-an-imageview) :

> `ImageView` does not have a built-in zoom control. Please use the search option before asking question, you would have found your answer : [How to make my ImageView zoomable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939103/how-to-make-my-imageview-zoomable) which mentions that there seems to be a way although there is no built in.