# How to detect Multi-touch event?

Tags: android, view, multi-touch, android-sdk-1.6

I am developing an application on Android SDK 1.5.
Is there an event to detect multi-touch ? How can I catch this event ?

Actually i am trying to zoom a picture by 2 fingers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995510/how-to-zoom-imageview-in-android

Comment: Thanks for fast response. But I don't know whether touched by 2 fingers or not. It is a big problem for me.

Comment: I've found a method that can determine touch count. int fingers = e.getPointerCount();
But this is available since 2.0. The main proposal is this issue should be available on 1.5 or 1.6. Any suggestion ? Guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

see pinch zoom example [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. But I am searching this issue on Android 1.5 or 1.6. I think it is absolutely available since 2.1.