# want to know how to zooming an image by double tap and stretching

Tags: java, android, layout, zooming

i saw couple of questions regarding this type but non of them are looking more promising. please give me the right idea by which i can zoom in and zoom out my image by stretching and double tap. I'm using android studio 3.5(latest version). you can recommend the tutorial link.

Comment: use this link [How To Zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3995808/7138532) and define another **if** for double tap.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [chrisbanes/PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView.git) library for android. It has all the zooming gestures and works perfectly fine. It has all the `ImageView` class methods as it is inherited from `ImageView`. Hope it works.