# Android ImageView Zoom-in and Zoom-Out

Tags: android, zooming, android-imageview, pinchzoom

I want to Zoom-in and Zoom-out an Android ImageView. I tried most of the samples but in all of them the image in the ImageView itself is getting Zoomed-in and Zoomed-out, while I want to Zoom-in and Zoom-out the ImageView. I want to increase the ImageView width and height while Zooming-in and reduce the ImageView width and height while Zooming-out. How do I achieve that?

Comment: go through this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846914/zooming-image-in-viewflipper

Comment: Google has provided an example for making zoom in/out view:
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

Comment: check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18221207/4251431) its awesome and `one line of code`

Comment: This example from Android is pretty solid, step by step instructions and source code provided.

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

Comment: Take an advantage of https://github.com/rahulkapoor1/ZommableLoadingImageView

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Make two java classes

Zoom class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Zoom extends View {

    private Drawable image;
    ImageButton img,img1;
    private int zoomControler=20;

    public Zoom(Context context){
            super(context);

            image=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.j);
            //image=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);

            setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //here u can control the width and height of the images........ this line is very important
        image.setBounds((getWidth()/2)-zoomControler, (getHeight()/2)-zoomControler, (getWidth()/2)+zoomControler, (getHeight()/2)+zoomControler);
        image.draw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP){
                    // zoom in
                    zoomControler+=10;
            }
            if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN){
                    // zoom out
                    zoomControler-=10;
            }
            if(zoomControler<10){
                    zoomControler=10;
            }

            invalidate();
            return true;
    }
}
```

make second class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Zoomexample extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
       super.onCreate(icicle);
       setContentView(new Zoom(this));
   }
}
```

Comment: i got error in... image=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.j); I copy an image in drawable folder. I renamed the image to j.. I got j cannot be resolved or is not a field..

Comment: @chinna_82, the image should be j.png and you should place it in Drawable folder. Then refresh your project and the error shouldn't be

Answer (score 227):

Please follow the below class, that is used for Zoom in and Zoom Out for ImageView.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ZoomInZoomOut extends Activity implements OnTouchListener 
{
    private static final String TAG = "Touch";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f,MAX_ZOOM = 1f;
    
    // These matrices will be used to scale points of the image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        float scale;

        dumpEvent(event);
        // Handle touch events here...

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
                                                matrix.set(view.getImageMatrix());
                                                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                                                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
                                                mode = DRAG;
                                                break;
            
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted
                
                                                mode = NONE;
                                                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                                                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down
                
                                                oldDist = spacing(event);
                                                Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                                                if (oldDist > 5f) {
                                                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                                    midPoint(mid, event);
                                                    mode = ZOOM;
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                                                }
                                                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                                                if (mode == DRAG) 
                                                { 
                                                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
                                                } 
                                                else if (mode == ZOOM) 
                                                { 
                                                    // pinch zooming
                                                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                                                    if (newDist > 5f) 
                                                    {
                                                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                        scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                                                                                    // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                                                                                    // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                                                                                    // zoom out
                                                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                break;
        }

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

        return true; // indicate event was handled
    }

    /*
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Method: spacing Parameters: MotionEvent Returns: float Description:
     * checks the spacing between the two fingers on touch
     * ----------------------------------------------------
     */
    
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /*
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
     * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
     * ------------------------------------------------------------
     */
    
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE","POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) 
        {
            sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
            sb.append(")");
        }

        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) 
        {
            sb.append("#").append(i);
            sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
            sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
            sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
            if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";");
        }
        
        sb.append("]");
        Log.d("Touch Events ---------", sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: whenever i tap on image it zooms. what should i do to stop it

Comment: I would really appreciate an answer to the comment above. The same happens to me. Is there any way to stop it from zooming in on the first tap? The `ImageView` itself is set to `centerFit`.

Comment: great works by @Chirag Raval.. how can i add panning effects now?

Comment: Has poor response and jumps all over the place.

Comment: @Baz, to avoid zooming on the first tap use `case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
                matrix.set(view.getImageMatrix());
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);` This will copy current scaling settings to the initial `matrix`

Comment: @user1386213 yes, you can.

Comment: I was searching for  matrix.set(view.getImageMatrix()); thanku @JohnnyDoe

Comment: How do we keep the image in the screen? Because I can keep scrolling it until it is very much out of view.

Comment: @CanCanbek I think that is what this is supposed to do. You can ask a new question if you can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: For those who use the above code, "return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);" replace it with "return (float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);" coz FloatMath is deprecated now. Cheers

Comment: @ChiragRaval can we use it on the layout ?  which contains multiples images ... I am trying to zoom and swipe left, right, up, down but couldn't find a way to accomplish it.

Comment: @ChiragRaval How to use this class for a imageView inserted in XML?

Comment: We can actually zoom out the original image to make it smaller. How to prevent this? Image should not go less than 100% of its original size.

Comment: Perfect class! One question, how can I log the X/Y-position on action up relative to the ImageView's X/Y-position. Now it registers all the white space around it... I want to know the coordinates inside my ImageView.

Comment: This is exactly what I want but for a bitmap in canvas for scaling

Comment: Kinda ugly to do all this stuff within an Activity

Comment: not so smooth when put it in a ScrollView with multiple images

Comment: How to avoid to much zoom out?

Comment: I can't seem to apply this on an ImageView added to WindowManager in a class extending Service class.

Comment: @Chirag could you update the code, when click on first tap moved to the top of the screen

Comment: This code is working fine, its purpose is to ZoomIn/ZoomOut a view not the image in it.

Comment: Using this code image is zoom in/out infinitely, how to restrict it?

Comment: This is a great sample.  Thanks to Chirag and @Nikunj Paradva.  I have two things that I want to add in my code, One, limit the min and max zoom size, and Two, have the click (touch) event to be handled (like navigate back).  I will work at this but if anyone has a suggestion...

Answer (score 108):

The other implementations here all have some kind of a flaw. so i basically mixed them up and came up with this.

Create a custom view like this:

ZoomableImageView.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ZoomableImageView extends ImageView
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    int mode = NONE;

    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 4f;
    float[] m;

    float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;
    float width, height;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight;

    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    Context context;

    public ZoomableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attr)
    {
        super(context, attr);
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    //when one finger is touching
                    //set the mode to DRAG
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;
                    //when two fingers are touching
                    //set the mode to ZOOM
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                        last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = ZOOM;
                        break;
                    //when a finger moves
                    //If mode is applicable move image
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        //if the mode is ZOOM or
                        //if the mode is DRAG and already zoomed
                        if (mode == ZOOM || (mode == DRAG && saveScale > minScale))
                        {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;// x difference
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;// y difference
                            float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);// width after applying current scale
                            float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);// height after applying current scale
                            //if scaleWidth is smaller than the views width
                            //in other words if the image width fits in the view
                            //limit left and right movement
                            if (scaleWidth < width)
                            {
                                deltaX = 0;
                                if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                    deltaY = -y;
                                else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                    deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                            }
                            //if scaleHeight is smaller than the views height
                            //in other words if the image height fits in the view
                            //limit up and down movement
                            else if (scaleHeight < height)
                            {
                                deltaY = 0;
                                if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                    deltaX = -x;
                                else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                    deltaX = -(x + right);
                            }
                            //if the image doesnt fit in the width or height
                            //limit both up and down and left and right
                            else
                            {
                                if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                    deltaX = -x;
                                else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                    deltaX = -(x + right);

                                if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                    deltaY = -y;
                                else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                    deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                            }
                            //move the image with the matrix
                            matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                            //set the last touch location to the current
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;
                    //first finger is lifted
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        break;
                    // second finger is lifted
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                }
                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true;
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)
    {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
        bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x)
    {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale)
            {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            }
            else if (saveScale < minScale)
            {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }
            right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
            bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
            if (origWidth * saveScale <= width || origHeight * saveScale <= height)
            {
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
                if (mScaleFactor < 1)
                {
                    matrix.getValues(m);
                    float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                    float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                    if (mScaleFactor < 1)
                    {
                        if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width)
                        {
                            if (y < -bottom)
                                matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                            else if (y > 0)
                                matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (x < -right)
                                matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                            else if (x > 0)
                                matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                    if (x < -right)
                        matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                    else if (x > 0)
                        matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    if (y < -bottom)
                        matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                    else if (y > 0)
                        matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        //Fit to screen.
        float scale;
        float scaleX =  width / bmWidth;
        float scaleY = height / bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        saveScale = 1f;

        // Center the image
        redundantYSpace = height - (scale * bmHeight) ;
        redundantXSpace = width - (scale * bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= 2;
        redundantXSpace /= 2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
}
```

Then add the image like this:

```
ZoomableImageView touch = (ZoomableImageView)findViewById(R.id.IMAGEID);
touch.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Add the view like this in XML:

```
<PACKAGE.ZoomableImageView
android:id="@+id/IMAGEID"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: I've gone through over a dozen of these implementations and none of them have smooth behavior, including this one.

Comment: Although I don't get why you write "fitCenter" works best, even though you call setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX) right in the constructor...?
However. Thanks!

Comment: Don' make fool of people who seek for an answer.This will not work if you change the scaletype to fitXy in the code where you have mentioned  SCaleType to MATRIX.

Comment: I didn't say you should change the scaletype to fitXy... And if you change the code its not my fault that it does not work. I provided you with a working solution that i've used before.

Comment: Hey @NicolasTyler , I'm using your solution and it works great! just one question: When I change the layout where the ZoomableImageView is in, the view is resized and updated but 'loses' its last state (zoom/position) (it's zoomed out to the initial state again). Do you know where it would be best to save the last state(matrix) and where to apply it again? (zooming and scrolling to the last position) Thanks!

Comment: Ask a new question and provide more info.

Comment: add this: ViewTreeObserver vto = getViewTreeObserver();
  vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
      public boolean onPreDraw() {
       bmHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
          bmWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
          return true;
      }
  });

Comment: This looks great but I need to make some modifications and I wish it was commented :( Im brushing up on my Algebra but I've been stuck on this for two days. Any chance you could add comments, most notably to the onTouch sections and what 'saveScale' means?

Comment: I will add comments, but its not that complicated, `saveScale` is the current scale value of the image, `minScale` being the smallest it can go and `maxScale` is the most the image can scale.

Comment: Thanks for the comments this is going to help immensely. I am going to attempt to get a different version of this pinch zoom added here to. Your solution is great for situations where you allow alpha space at max zoom out, I am designing a version where you cannot zoom past the minimum ratio that would lead to having alpha space.

Comment: @NicolasTyler And how would i use this class in some other package and activity?

Comment: @Nicolas Can this zoom in and out achieved only by dragging like when I drag Image it zooms and when I drag out it resizes to original?

Comment: I wrote this 2 years ago, i havent tested it but it was meant to be pinch zoom and drag to move image.

Comment: @NicolasTyler  Hi this is working fine what i want u gave here, thank you very much and i need image rotation with the same feature. could u please provide this as soon as possible.

Comment: No need to use `setOnTouchListener()` you can just override `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`

Comment: Working great. How can I get the *real* image x,y coordinates when a click was performed?

Comment: Doesn't work when image is inside ViewPager. Shows empty screen. While similar solutions and derived projects work

Comment: I am using your class in a kotlin project. All I had to do is to replace the ImageView with your ZoomableImageView in the layout xml and it did work out of the box! Thanks.

Answer (score 35):

**Simple way:**

```
PhotoViewAttacher pAttacher;
pAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(Your_Image_View);
pAttacher.update();
```

Add below line in `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
```

Comment: Good, but this is only for imageview. How to attach a Class extended by View to this attacher. Have you any idea,

Comment: This works very well. I trid other answers and they did not work, or did not work properly.

Comment: This is an outdated version. See the repo for instructions for latest PhotoView: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: Although the PhotoView according to above links instructions it does not work. Your answer (PhotoViewAttacher) seems to work

Answer (score 27):

I have improved the answer I got from stack for flawless **ZOOM (two finger) / ROTATION (two finger) / DRAG (Single finger)**.

[image]

//============================XML code==================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.flochat.imageviewzoomforstack.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_trash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/trash" />

</LinearLayout>
```

//============================Java code==========================

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView photoview2;
    float[] lastEvent = null;
    float d = 0f;
    float newRot = 0f;
    private boolean isZoomAndRotate;
    private boolean isOutSide;
    private static final int NONE = 0;
    private static final int DRAG = 1;
    private static final int ZOOM = 2;
    private int mode = NONE;
    private PointF start = new PointF();
    private PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;
    private float xCoOrdinate, yCoOrdinate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        photoview2 = findViewById(R.id.imageview_trash);

        photoview2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                view.bringToFront();
                viewTransformation(view, event);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    private void viewTransformation(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            xCoOrdinate = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
            yCoOrdinate = view.getY() - event.getRawY();

                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                isOutSide = false;
                mode = DRAG;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }

                lastEvent = new float[4];
                lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                d = rotation(event);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                isZoomAndRotate = false;
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    float x = event.getX();
                    float y = event.getY();
                }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                isOutSide = true;
                mode = NONE;
                lastEvent = null;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (!isOutSide) {
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        isZoomAndRotate = false;
                        view.animate().x(event.getRawX() + xCoOrdinate).y(event.getRawY() + yCoOrdinate).setDuration(0).start();
                    }
                    if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                        float newDist1 = spacing(event);
                        if (newDist1 > 10f) {
                            float scale = newDist1 / oldDist * view.getScaleX();
                            view.setScaleX(scale);
                            view.setScaleY(scale);
                        }
                        if (lastEvent != null) {
                            newRot = rotation(event);
                            view.setRotation((float) (view.getRotation() + (newRot - d)));
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
        double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
        double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
        double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
        return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
    }

    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (int) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

}
```

//========================Just pass any view which you want to zoom/rotate/drag to viewTransformation() method. Very applicable for textview zoom. It will not pixelate text.

Answer (score 22):

It's old, but this may help someone else.

Below TouchImageView class supports both zooming in/out on either pinch or double tap

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TouchImageView extends ImageView implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

    Matrix matrix;

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;

    int viewWidth, viewHeight;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    protected float origWidth, origHeight;
    int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    Context context;

    public TouchImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
        mGestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);

        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        matrix = new Matrix();
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(curr);
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth,
                                    origWidth * saveScale);
                            float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight,
                                    origHeight * saveScale);
                            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                            fixTrans();
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                }

                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }

        });
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        // Double tap is detected
        Log.i("MAIN_TAG", "Double tap detected");
        float origScale = saveScale;
        float mScaleFactor;

        if (saveScale == maxScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        } else {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        }

        matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                viewHeight / 2);

        fixTrans();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }

            if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                    || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                        viewHeight / 2);
            else
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                        detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

            fixTrans();
            return true;
        }
    }

    void fixTrans() {
        matrix.getValues(m);
        float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
        float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
                * saveScale);

        if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
    }

    float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        float minTrans, maxTrans;

        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            minTrans = 0;
            maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        } else {
            minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            maxTrans = 0;
        }

        if (trans < minTrans)
            return -trans + minTrans;
        if (trans > maxTrans)
            return -trans + maxTrans;
        return 0;
    }

    float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            return 0;
        }
        return delta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        //
        // Rescales image on rotation
        //
        if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
                || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
            return;
        oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
        oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

        if (saveScale == 1) {
            // Fit to screen.
            float scale;

            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
            if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                    || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
                return;
            int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

            Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

            float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
            float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
            scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

            // Center the image
            float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                    - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
            float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                    - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
            redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
            redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

            matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

            origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
            origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
        fixTrans();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**
You can replace your `ImageView` with TouchImageView in both XML & java

**1. For XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.android.myapp.TouchImageView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imViewedImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true" />
```

**2. For Java**

```
TouchImageView imViewedImage = findViewById(R.id.imViewedImage);
```

Comment: I start it with setImageURI(imageUri) and every image appears black...
The view does get the correct size, height and different attributes but doesnt display anything no matter the image.

Comment: @SuppressWarnings thanks for notifying that, I am not sure if I tried to set it programmatically; need to look back.. and will mention you for any workaround :)

Comment: This works but it's not zooming into the zone where you double-tap + pinch to zoom have a certain limitation.

Answer (score 18):

just use this class : [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)

Comment: Follow our community guidelines . Do not provide external links because links in the future may not be accessible. Furthermore, give some snippet code.

Answer (score 17):

This is yet another implementation based on the code posted by Nicolas Tyler.

The following bugs are fixed:

- Setting `minScale` to a number less than 1 now works
- You don't need to use `setImageBitmap()` to set the image (you can use, for example `setImageResource()`
- All constructors now work properly

The following things, amongst others are tidied up:

- An `OnTouchListener` is not used, it's not necessary because the the class can just implement the `onTouchEvent()` method.
- The assignment `right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);` has been simplified to `right = (originalBitmapWidth * saveScale) - width` Which, in my option, is much less confusing.
- Some member variables are removed (more state can probably be removed from this class)

It's not perfect but here you go:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by alex on 23/02/16.
 * Based on code posted by Nicolas Tyler here:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out
 */
public class ZoomableImageView extends ImageView {

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float newScale = saveScale * scaleFactor;
            if (newScale < maxScale && newScale > minScale) {
                saveScale = newScale;
                float width = getWidth();
                float height = getHeight();
                right = (originalBitmapWidth * saveScale) - width;
                bottom = (originalBitmapHeight * saveScale) - height;

                float scaledBitmapWidth = originalBitmapWidth * saveScale;
                float scaledBitmapHeight = originalBitmapHeight * saveScale;

                if (scaledBitmapWidth <= width || scaledBitmapHeight <= height) {
                    matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
                } else {
                    matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    static final int CLICK = 3;

    private int mode = NONE;

    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    private PointF last = new PointF();
    private PointF start = new PointF();
    private float minScale = 0.5f;
    private float maxScale = 4f;
    private float[] m;

    private float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;
    private float saveScale = 1f;
    private float right, bottom, originalBitmapWidth, originalBitmapHeight;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    public ZoomableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(true);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int bmHeight = getBmHeight();
        int bmWidth = getBmWidth();

        float width = getMeasuredWidth();
        float height = getMeasuredHeight();
        //Fit to screen.
        float scale = width > height ? height / bmHeight :  width / bmWidth;

        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        saveScale = 1f;

        originalBitmapWidth = scale * bmWidth;
        originalBitmapHeight = scale * bmHeight;

        // Center the image
        redundantYSpace = (height - originalBitmapHeight);
        redundantXSpace = (width - originalBitmapWidth);

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace / 2, redundantYSpace / 2);

        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        matrix.getValues(m);
        float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
        PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            //when one finger is touching
            //set the mode to DRAG
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                start.set(last);
                mode = DRAG;
                break;
            //when two fingers are touching
            //set the mode to ZOOM
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                start.set(last);
                mode = ZOOM;
                break;
            //when a finger moves
            //If mode is applicable move image
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //if the mode is ZOOM or
                //if the mode is DRAG and already zoomed
                if (mode == ZOOM || (mode == DRAG && saveScale > minScale)) {
                    float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;// x difference
                    float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;// y difference
                    float scaleWidth = Math.round(originalBitmapWidth * saveScale);// width after applying current scale
                    float scaleHeight = Math.round(originalBitmapHeight * saveScale);// height after applying current scale

                    boolean limitX = false;
                    boolean limitY = false;

                    //if scaleWidth is smaller than the views width
                    //in other words if the image width fits in the view
                    //limit left and right movement
                    if (scaleWidth < getWidth() && scaleHeight < getHeight()) {
                        // don't do anything
                    }
                    else if (scaleWidth < getWidth()) {
                        deltaX = 0;
                        limitY = true;
                    }
                    //if scaleHeight is smaller than the views height
                    //in other words if the image height fits in the view
                    //limit up and down movement
                    else if (scaleHeight < getHeight()) {
                        deltaY = 0;
                        limitX = true;
                    }
                    //if the image doesnt fit in the width or height
                    //limit both up and down and left and right
                    else {
                        limitX = true;
                        limitY = true;
                    }

                    if (limitY) {
                        if (y + deltaY > 0) {
                            deltaY = -y;
                        } else  if (y + deltaY < -bottom) {
                            deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                        }

                    }

                    if (limitX) {
                        if (x + deltaX > 0) {
                            deltaX = -x;
                        } else if (x + deltaX < -right) {
                            deltaX = -(x + right);
                        }

                    }
                    //move the image with the matrix
                    matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                    //set the last touch location to the current
                    last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                }
                break;
            //first finger is lifted
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                    performClick();
                break;
            // second finger is lifted
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;
        }
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    private int getBmWidth() {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable != null) {
            return drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private int getBmHeight() {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable != null) {
            return drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great job. I modified a bit your code. I disabled the ability to move the image on X or Y if the width or  height is less then display's bounds

Comment: @ROHITPARMAR I will post a new comment with my class.

Comment: is there a way to restore the scaling of image when the `ImageView` is double tapped?

Comment: Thanks! Works nice. If you use this widget inside `ViewPager`, some difficulties appear. 1) A scale is not reset to 1 after moving forward and backward. 2) If you try to shift a picture, the movement is slow and short. And you can occasionally move to next picture. It's not a problem of the solution, but you should realize a new behaviour.

Comment: You added `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` in `onScale` method, where is the implementation of them?

Comment: I really needed this kind of behaviour. Simple zoom and drag, no rotation and nothing else.

Answer (score 8):

I made my own custom imageview with pinch to zoom. There is no limits/borders on [Chirag Raval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6650484/1888162)s code, so user can drag the image off the screen.

Here is the CustomImageView class:

```
    public class CustomImageVIew extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener {


    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;

    private int mode = NONE;

    private PointF mStartPoint = new PointF();
    private PointF mMiddlePoint = new PointF();
    private Point mBitmapMiddlePoint = new Point();

    private float oldDist = 1f;
    private float matrixValues[] = {0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f};
    private float scale;
    private float oldEventX = 0;
    private float oldEventY = 0;
    private float oldStartPointX = 0;
    private float oldStartPointY = 0;
    private int mViewWidth = -1;
    private int mViewHeight = -1;
    private int mBitmapWidth = -1;
    private int mBitmapHeight = -1;
    private boolean mDraggable = false;


    public CustomImageVIew(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public CustomImageVIew(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomImageVIew(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mViewWidth = w;
        mViewHeight = h;
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
        if(bitmap != null){
            setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            mBitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
            mBitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
            mBitmapMiddlePoint.x = (mViewWidth / 2) - (mBitmapWidth /  2);
            mBitmapMiddlePoint.y = (mViewHeight / 2) - (mBitmapHeight / 2);

            matrix.postTranslate(mBitmapMiddlePoint.x, mBitmapMiddlePoint.y);
            this.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            mStartPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            if(oldDist > 10f){
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mMiddlePoint, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(mode == DRAG){
                drag(event);
            } else if(mode == ZOOM){
                zoom(event);
            } 
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }



   public void drag(MotionEvent event){
       matrix.getValues(matrixValues);

       float left = matrixValues[2];
       float top = matrixValues[5];
       float bottom = (top + (matrixValues[0] * mBitmapHeight)) - mViewHeight;
       float right = (left + (matrixValues[0] * mBitmapWidth)) -mViewWidth;

       float eventX = event.getX();
       float eventY = event.getY();
       float spacingX = eventX - mStartPoint.x;
       float spacingY = eventY - mStartPoint.y;
       float newPositionLeft = (left  < 0 ? spacingX : spacingX * -1) + left;
       float newPositionRight = (spacingX) + right;
       float newPositionTop = (top  < 0 ? spacingY : spacingY * -1) + top;
       float newPositionBottom = (spacingY) + bottom;
       boolean x = true;
       boolean y = true;

       if(newPositionRight < 0.0f || newPositionLeft > 0.0f){
           if(newPositionRight < 0.0f && newPositionLeft > 0.0f){
               x = false;
           } else{
               eventX = oldEventX;
               mStartPoint.x = oldStartPointX;
           }
       }
       if(newPositionBottom < 0.0f || newPositionTop > 0.0f){
           if(newPositionBottom < 0.0f && newPositionTop > 0.0f){
               y = false;
           } else{
               eventY = oldEventY;
               mStartPoint.y = oldStartPointY;
           }
       }

       if(mDraggable){
           matrix.set(savedMatrix);
           matrix.postTranslate(x? eventX - mStartPoint.x : 0, y? eventY - mStartPoint.y : 0);
           this.setImageMatrix(matrix);
           if(x)oldEventX = eventX;
           if(y)oldEventY = eventY;
           if(x)oldStartPointX = mStartPoint.x;
           if(y)oldStartPointY = mStartPoint.y;
       }

   }

   public void zoom(MotionEvent event){
       matrix.getValues(matrixValues);

       float newDist = spacing(event);
       float bitmapWidth = matrixValues[0] * mBitmapWidth;
       float bimtapHeight = matrixValues[0] * mBitmapHeight;
       boolean in = newDist > oldDist;

       if(!in && matrixValues[0] < 1){
           return;
       }
       if(bitmapWidth > mViewWidth || bimtapHeight > mViewHeight){
           mDraggable = true;
       } else{
           mDraggable = false;
       }

       float midX = (mViewWidth / 2);
       float midY = (mViewHeight / 2);

       matrix.set(savedMatrix);
       scale = newDist / oldDist;
       matrix.postScale(scale, scale, bitmapWidth > mViewWidth ? mMiddlePoint.x : midX, bimtapHeight > mViewHeight ? mMiddlePoint.y : midY); 

       this.setImageMatrix(matrix);


   }





    /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);

        return (float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }


}
```

This is how you can use it in your activity:

```
CustomImageVIew mImageView = (CustomImageVIew)findViewById(R.id.customImageVIew1);
mImage.setBitmap(your bitmap);
```

And layout:

```
<your.package.name.CustomImageVIew
        android:id="@+id/customImageVIew1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:scaleType="matrix"/> // important
```

Comment: OK, best implementation so far.  My main issue with this implementation is that from the get go the image is displayed at 1:1 ratio and we cannot perform zoom out. Apart from that, it is my fav implementation thus far on this thread

Answer (score 6):

You should put the image in webview and work with that. Zoom in / out controls are available in webview.

- http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/09/18/using-webview-as-a-image-zoom-view-control/
- http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/121522-how-display-image-sdcard-webview.html

Answer (score 6):

I think Chirag Ravals' answer is great!

The only thing it could be improved is moving all this code inside some class like:

```
PinchZoomImageView extends ImageView {...
```

and adding there initial Image Matrix initialization to prevent zooming after the first tap:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    matrix = new Matrix(this.getImageMatrix());
}
```

BTW, this will fix a bug mentioned by Muhammad Umar and Baz

P.S. Having Max and Min zoom limits could be also useful.
E.g Max zoom is 2X and min zoom is the original scale when the image is fitted to screen:

```
static final int MAX_SCALE_FACTOR = 2;

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    // Getting initial Image matrix
    mViewMatrix = new Matrix(this.getImageMatrix());
    mMinScaleMatrix = new Matrix(mViewMatrix);
    float initialScale = getMatrixScale(mViewMatrix);


    if (initialScale < 1.0f) // Image is bigger than screen
        mMaxScale = MAX_SCALE_FACTOR;
    else
        mMaxScale = MAX_SCALE_FACTOR * initialScale;

    mMinScale = getMatrixScale(mMinScaleMatrix);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    // We set scale only after onMeasure was called and automatically fit image to screen
    if(!mWasScaleTypeSet) {
        view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        mWasScaleTypeSet = true;
    }

    float scale;

    dumpEvent(event);

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // first finger down only
        mCurSavedMatrix.set(mViewMatrix);
        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
        mCurrentMode = DRAG;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted
        mCurrentMode = NONE;

        float resScale = getMatrixScale(mViewMatrix);

        if (resScale > mMaxScale) {
            downscaleMatrix(resScale, mViewMatrix);
        } else if (resScale < mMinScale)
            mViewMatrix = new Matrix(mMinScaleMatrix);
        else if ((resScale - mMinScale) < 0.1f) // Don't allow user to drag picture outside in case of FIT TO WINDOW zoom
            mViewMatrix = new Matrix(mMinScaleMatrix);
        else
            break;

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down
        mOldDist = spacing(event);
        Helper.LOGD(TAG, "oldDist=" + mOldDist);
        if (mOldDist > 5f) {
            mCurSavedMatrix.set(mViewMatrix);
            midPoint(mCurMidPoint, event);
            mCurrentMode = ZOOM;
            Helper.LOGD(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
        }
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (mCurrentMode == DRAG) {
            mViewMatrix.set(mCurSavedMatrix);
            mViewMatrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
        } else if (mCurrentMode == ZOOM) {
            // pinch zooming
            float newDist = spacing(event);
            Helper.LOGD(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
            if (newDist > 1.f) {
                mViewMatrix.set(mCurSavedMatrix);
                scale = newDist / mOldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                                            // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                                            // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                                            // zoom out
                mViewMatrix.postScale(scale, scale, mCurMidPoint.x, mCurMidPoint.y);
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    view.setImageMatrix(mViewMatrix); // display the transformation on screen

    return true; // indicate event was handled
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////// PRIVATE SECTION ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// These matrices will be used to scale points of the image
private Matrix mViewMatrix = new Matrix();
private Matrix mCurSavedMatrix = new Matrix();
// These PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
private PointF start = new PointF();
private PointF mCurMidPoint = new PointF();
private float mOldDist = 1f;

private Matrix mMinScaleMatrix;
private float mMinScale;
private float mMaxScale;
float[] mTmpValues = new float[9];
private boolean mWasScaleTypeSet;


/**
 * Returns scale factor of the Matrix
 * @param matrix
 * @return
 */
private float getMatrixScale(Matrix matrix) {
    matrix.getValues(mTmpValues);
    return mTmpValues[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
}

/**
 * Downscales matrix with the scale to maximum allowed scale factor, but the same translations
 * @param scale
 * @param dist
 */
private void downscaleMatrix(float scale, Matrix dist) {
    float resScale = mMaxScale / scale;
    dist.postScale(resScale, resScale, mCurMidPoint.x, mCurMidPoint.y);
}
```

Comment: For some reason, `matrix = new Matrix(this.getImageMatrix());` line makes the image disappear for me. Do you know why?

Comment: If you do it inside onMeasure() the matrix will just obtain the correct value according to current View zoom default scale. And this matrix will be used only after the next interaction with user (tap for example). And when did you image disappear?

Comment: @goRGon Hi, In my application i set image with fit to screen. And i want to zoom apart from screen size which is working fine. And I need to zoom out,drag,rotate the image which is done only outside of the screen not inside of the screen. pls help me how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

I got the most helpful answer from @Nicolas Tyler but I had issues with how the syntax and logic worked. I also did not want any Alpha space and my Algebra was rusty! After 3 days I have put together my own version of this.

**My answer differs from @Nicolas Tyler with the following:**

1. Different variable names which I found made more sense in underlying contextual uses
2. This Pinch-Zoom image class does NOT show alpha space and will let you zoom in and out and still not let you over/under pan an image and reveal alpha space
3. Added deep comments to the matrix section to explain what was going on with the math involved
4. This image class will also let you pass in a resourceId and it will create a bitmap from it
5. Much simpler algorithms for both scaling and translation and few variables
6. Changing the image within this will cause it to zoom in/out such that the new image takes up the view container

A great resource refresher on Algebra can be found here:
https://youtu.be/IiXB6tYtY4w?t=4m12s
That video covers the core of Scalar and Translation matrixes (and will help you make sense of the MTRANS_X and MTRANS_Y stuff). If you have questions ask and I will do my best to answer (but I am NO Algebra expert).

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class iImage extends ImageView
{
    static final int NONE_MODE = 0;
    static final int DRAG_MODE = 1;
    static final int ZOOM_MODE = 2;
    int _mode = NONE_MODE;

    Matrix _matrix = new Matrix();
    PointF _previousPoint = new PointF();
    PointF _startPoint = new PointF();
    float _currentScale = 1f;
    float _minScale = 1f;
    float _maxScale = 3f;
    float[] _arrayOf9Floats;
    float _bitmapWidth, _bitmapHeight,_displayWidth, _displayHeight;
    ScaleGestureDetector _scaleDetector;
    Context _context;

    public iImage(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        super.setClickable(true);
        _context = context;
        _scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        _arrayOf9Floats = new float[9];
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return handleTouch(v, event);
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean handleTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        _scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        //Contrary to how this line looks, the matrix is not setting the values from the arrayOf9Floats, but rather taking the
        //matrix values and assigning them into the arrayOf9Floats. I extremely dislike this syntax and I think
        //it should have been written as _arrayOf9Floats = _matrix.getValues() but that's Android for you!!!
        _matrix.getValues(_arrayOf9Floats);

        //Look at https://youtu.be/IiXB6tYtY4w?t=4m12s , it shows scale, rotate, and translate matrices
        //If you look at the translate matrix, you'll see that the 3rd and 6th values are the values which represent x and y translations respectively
        //this corresponds to the 2nd and 5th values in the array and hence why the MTRANS_X and MTRANS_Y have the constants 2 and 5 respectively
        float xTranslate = _arrayOf9Floats[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float yTranslate = _arrayOf9Floats[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
        PointF currentEventPoint = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            //First finger down only
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                _previousPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                _startPoint.set(_previousPoint);
                _mode = DRAG_MODE;
                break;
            //Second finger down
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                _previousPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                _startPoint.set(_previousPoint);
                _mode = ZOOM_MODE;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (_mode == ZOOM_MODE || _mode == DRAG_MODE )
                {
                    float deltaX = currentEventPoint.x - _previousPoint.x;
                    float deltaY = currentEventPoint.y - _previousPoint.y;
                    //In matrix terms, going right is + and going left is +
                    //Moving the image right past 0 means it will show alpha space on the left so we dont want that
                    //Keep in mind this is a TOP LEFT pivot point, so we dont want the top left to be past 0 lest we have alpha space
                    if(xTranslate + deltaX > 0)
                    {
                        //get absolute of how much into the negative we would have gone
                        float excessDeltaX = Math.abs(xTranslate + deltaX);
                        //take that excess away from deltaX so X wont got less than 0 after the translation
                        deltaX = deltaX - excessDeltaX;
                    }

                    //Going left we dont want the negative value to be less than the negative width of the sprite, lest we get alpha space on the right
                    //The width is going to be the width of the bitmap * scale and we want the - of it because we are checking for left movement
                    //We also need to account for the width of the DISPLAY CONTAINER (i.e. _displayWidth) so that gets subtracted
                    //i.e. we want the max scroll width value
                    float maxScrollableWidth = _bitmapWidth * _currentScale - _displayWidth;
                    if(xTranslate + deltaX < -maxScrollableWidth)
                    {
                        //this forces the max possible translate to always match the - of maxScrollableWidth
                        deltaX = -maxScrollableWidth - xTranslate;
                    }

                    //repeat for Y
                    if(yTranslate + deltaY > 0)
                    {
                        float excessDeltaY = Math.abs(yTranslate + deltaY);
                        deltaY = deltaY - excessDeltaY;
                    }

                    float maxScrollableHeight = _bitmapHeight * _currentScale - _displayWidth;
                    if(yTranslate + deltaY < -maxScrollableHeight)
                    {
                        //this forces the max possible translate to always match the - of maxScrollableWidth
                        deltaY = -maxScrollableHeight - yTranslate;
                    }

                    _matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                    _matrix.getValues(_arrayOf9Floats);
                    //System.out.println(_matrix);

                    _previousPoint.set(currentEventPoint.x, currentEventPoint.y);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                _mode = NONE_MODE;
                break;
        }
        setImageMatrix(_matrix);
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)
    {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        _bitmapWidth = bm.getWidth();
        _bitmapHeight = bm.getHeight();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageResource(int resid)
    {
        Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(_context.getResources(), resid);
        setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            _mode = ZOOM_MODE;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            float scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float originalScale = _currentScale;
            _currentScale *= scaleFactor;
            //Zoom in too much
            if (_currentScale > _maxScale) {
                _currentScale = _maxScale;
                scaleFactor = _maxScale / originalScale;
            }//Zoom out too much
            else if (_currentScale < _minScale) {
                _currentScale = _minScale;
                scaleFactor = _minScale / originalScale;
            }
           _matrix.postScale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);

            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        _displayWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        _displayHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        adjustScale();
    }

    private void adjustScale()
    {
        //Fit to display bounds with NO alpha space
        float scale;
        float scaleX =  _displayWidth / _bitmapWidth;
        float scaleY = _displayHeight / _bitmapHeight;
        scale = Math.max(scaleX, scaleY);
        _matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        setImageMatrix(_matrix);
        _currentScale = scale;
        _minScale = scale;
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float maxZoom){_maxScale = maxZoom;}
    public void setMinZoom(float minZoom) {_minScale = minZoom;}
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of "alpha space"?

Comment: It work's great and really is a much cleaner solution than the original. One thing you missed though is that the scale gesture always scale to the top left corner of the image, instead of in between the fingers. i'm going to try and fix it, so if you have any hints for me it would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I found that replacing `mMatrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);` with `mMatrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());` inside `public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)` is doing the trick when you zoom in. more code is needed to support zoom out. but for now, it is enough for me.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to initialize it? In mainactivity. I removed `android:src` and `android:scaleType` from the xml file. How to add the image which is in "drawable" folder to it.

Comment: There are some issues with this:

* The initial zoom is wrong (Possible solution use `scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);` in `adjustScale()`. 
* The zooming does not follow the mid point between fingers

Comment: Strange, but after replacing `ImageView` in XML with `iImage`, I got "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ...iImage".

Answer (score 6):

This code works and implement the double tap to return to original image size.

1st step - In your xml layout put this:

```
<com.****.*****.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/action_infolinks_splash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@mipmap/myinfolinks_splash"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:contentDescription="@string/aboutSupport_description_image"/>
```

2nd step- Create a file (TouchImageView.java) with the TouchImageView class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

    Matrix matrix;

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;
    float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace, origRedundantXSpace, origRedundantYSpace;

    int viewWidth, viewHeight;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    static final float SAVE_SCALE = 1f;
    float saveScale = SAVE_SCALE;
    protected float origWidth, origHeight;
    int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;
    float origScale, bottom, origBottom, right, origRight;

    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    Context context;

    public TouchImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        matrix = new Matrix();
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                boolean onDoubleTapEvent = mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                if (onDoubleTapEvent) {
                    // Reset Image to original scale values
                    mode = NONE;
                    bottom = origBottom;
                    right = origRight;
                    last = new PointF();
                    start = new PointF();
                    m = new float[9];
                    saveScale = SAVE_SCALE;
                    matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.setScale(origScale, origScale);
                    matrix.postTranslate(origRedundantXSpace, origRedundantYSpace);
                    setImageMatrix(matrix);
                    invalidate();
                    return true;
                }

                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(curr);
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
                            float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);
                            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                            fixTrans();
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK) performClick();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                }

                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }

        });

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            //float mScaleFactor = (float) Math.min(Math.max(.95f, detector.getScaleFactor()), 1.05);
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }

            right = viewWidth * saveScale - viewWidth - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
            bottom = viewHeight * saveScale - viewHeight - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);

            if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
            else
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

            fixTrans();
            return true;
        }
    }

    void fixTrans() {
        matrix.getValues(m);
        float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
        float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);

        if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
    }

    float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        float minTrans, maxTrans;

        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            minTrans = 0;
            maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        } else {
            minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            maxTrans = 0;
        }

        if (trans < minTrans)
            return -trans + minTrans;
        if (trans > maxTrans)
            return -trans + maxTrans;
        return 0;
    }

    float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            return 0;
        }
        return delta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        //
        // Rescales image on rotation
        //
        if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0) return;

        oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
        oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

        if (saveScale == 1) {
            // Fit to screen.
            float scale;
            int bmWidth,bmHeight;

            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.myinfolinks_splash);
            bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
            bmHeight = bm.getHeight();

            int  w = bmWidth;
            int  h = bmHeight;
            viewWidth = resolveSize(w, widthMeasureSpec);
            viewHeight = resolveSize(h, heightMeasureSpec);

            float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
            float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
            scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
            saveScale = SAVE_SCALE;
            origScale = scale;

            // Center the image
            redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
            redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
            redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
            redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

            origRedundantXSpace = redundantXSpace;
            origRedundantYSpace = redundantYSpace;

            matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

            origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
            origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;

            right = viewWidth * saveScale - viewWidth - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
            bottom = viewHeight * saveScale - viewHeight - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
            origRight = right;
            origBottom = bottom;

            setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
        fixTrans();
    }
}
```

And finally, make the call in your main activity:

```
TouchImageView imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) messageView.findViewById(R.id.id_myImage);
imgDisplay.setMaxZoom(2f);
imgDisplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.myImage);
```

I saw lots of code and after my adjustments it's working. Enjoy!

Comment: For better perform change this line: Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.myinfolinks_splash); for this one: ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.action_infolinks_splash);

Comment: And you don't need this (it's already set in the xml layout): imgDisplay.setImageResource(R.mipmap.myinfolinks_splash);

Comment: Skizo- this:  ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.action_infolinks_splash)

Comment: Skizo- this:  ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.action_infolinks_splash) it's for to get the width&height image programmatically. Yesterday i improve the code to rescale and i use only xxhdpi jpg image (1026px x 770px), like that i make smaller app and the image adjust for all screen size sucessfuly.

Comment: In xml:  <***.****.TouchImageView
                android:id="@+id/action_infolinks_about_support"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/myinfolinks_about_support"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:contentDescription="@string/aboutSupport_description_image"/>

Comment: But does it zoom in zoom out repeatly? I mean with 1 click it zooms in zooms out repeatly

Comment: I want when click an ImageView it zooms in and zooms out infinity with your answer can I do it?

Comment: I have been using this for a while, but now I wanted to use it with Glide and it won't show the image, then I updated the reference to android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView and get it works.

Comment: how to make it zoom in with double tap when in original size?

Answer (score 6):

Step 1:
 **First you add dependencies in build.gradle(Module:app) file.**

```
dependencies {

     implementation 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.2.0'

    }
```

Step 2:
**Next create a class**

> **ImageFullScreenFragment.java**

```
public class ImageFullScreenFragment{

   private ZoomageView ImageZoomageView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = null;

      try {
         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_full_screen, container, false);
            ImageZoomageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewImageFullScreen);
            ImageZoomageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);

         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    return view;

}
```

Step 3 :
**Next create a layout xml file**

> **fragment_image_full_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.jsibbold.zoomage.ZoomageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:zoomage_restrictBounds="false"
        app:zoomage_animateOnReset="true"
        app:zoomage_autoResetMode="UNDER"
        app:zoomage_autoCenter="true"
        app:zoomage_zoomable="true"
        app:zoomage_translatable="true"
        app:zoomage_minScale="0.6"
        app:zoomage_maxScale="8"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewImageFullScreen"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OutPut:-**

[image: Normal Image]

[image: Zoom-In Image]

[image: Zoom-In Image]

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
package com.example.nwssugeoinformationmobileapplication;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  OnTouchListener {

    private static final String TAG = "Touch";
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    private ImageView view;
    private float[] matrixValues = new float[9];
    private float maxZoom;
    private float minZoom;
    private float height;
    private float width;
    private RectF viewRect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById (R.id.tabhost);
        th.setup();

        TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        specs.setIndicator("Map");
        th.addTab(specs);


        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        specs.setIndicator("Search");
        th.addTab(specs);


        view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Drawable bitmap = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map);
        view.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this); 

        matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);



    } 



    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus){
    init();
            }
    }
    private void init() {
        maxZoom = 2;
        minZoom = 1f;
        height = view.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
        width = view.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menus, menu);
        return true; 
        }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId()== R.id.item1){
            Log.d("Tracks", "Track Us was Clicked");

            startActivity(new Intent (MainActivity.this, Tracklocation.class ));
            }

        if(item.getItemId()== R.id.item2){
            Log.d("Updates", "Updates was Clicked");

            startActivity(new Intent (MainActivity.this, Updates.class ));
            }

        if(item.getItemId()== R.id.item3){
            Log.d("About Us", "About Us was Clicked");


            startActivity(new Intent (MainActivity.this, Horoscope.class ));
            }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

     }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent rawEvent) {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        dumpEvent(rawEvent);
    // Handle touch events here...
    switch (rawEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
    start.set(rawEvent.getX(), rawEvent.getY());
    Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
    mode = DRAG;
    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
    oldDist = spacing(rawEvent);
    Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
    if (oldDist > 10f) {
    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
    midPoint(mid, rawEvent);
    mode = ZOOM;
    Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
    }
    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
    mode = NONE;
    Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    if (mode == DRAG) {
    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
    // limit pan
    matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
    float currentY = matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
    float currentX = matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float currentScale = matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    float currentHeight = height * currentScale;
    float currentWidth = width * currentScale;
    float dx = rawEvent.getX() - start.x;
    float dy = rawEvent.getY() - start.y;
    float newX = currentX+dx;
    float newY = currentY+dy;
    RectF drawingRect = new RectF(newX, newY, newX+currentWidth, newY+currentHeight);
    float diffUp = Math.min(viewRect.bottom-drawingRect.bottom, viewRect.top-drawingRect.top);
    float diffDown = Math.max(viewRect.bottom-drawingRect.bottom, viewRect.top-drawingRect.top);
    float diffLeft = Math.min(viewRect.left-drawingRect.left, viewRect.right-drawingRect.right);
    float diffRight = Math.max(viewRect.left-drawingRect.left, viewRect.right-drawingRect.right);

    if(diffUp > 0 ){
    dy +=diffUp;
    }
    if(diffDown < 0){
    dy +=diffDown;
    }
    if( diffLeft> 0){
    dx += diffLeft;
    }
    if(diffRight < 0){
    dx += diffRight;
    }
    matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
    } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
    float newDist = spacing(rawEvent);
    Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
    if (newDist > 10f) {
    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
    float scale1 = newDist / oldDist;
    matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
    float currentScale = matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    // limit zoom
    if (scale1 * currentScale > maxZoom) {
    scale1 = maxZoom / currentScale;
    } else if (scale1 * currentScale < minZoom) {
    scale1 = minZoom / currentScale;
    }
    matrix.postScale(scale1, scale1, mid.x, mid.y);
    }
    }
    break;
    }
    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return true; 
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
        "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
        || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
        sb.append("(pid ").append(
        action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
        sb.append(")");
        }
        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
        sb.append("#").append(i);
        sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
        sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
        sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
        if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
        sb.append(";");
        }
        sb.append("]");
        Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
        }
        /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
        private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        }
        /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
        @SuppressLint("FloatMath")
        private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed something similar, but needed the ability to get the dimensions easily and also drag/drop.  I based this off of the answer @Nicolas Tyler gave and modified it from there.

The features are pinch zoom in/out, long press to vibration/highlighted drag/drop.

To use it add this CustomZoomView class to your project.

```
public class CustomZoomView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener, View.OnLongClickListener{


private Paint mPaint;

Vibrator v;

static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
static final int MOVE = 3;

private int mode = NONE;

Rect src;
Rect mTempDst = new Rect();
Rect dst = new Rect();

Bitmap mBitmap;

private int mBitmapWidth = -1;
private int mBitmapHeight = -1;

private PointF mStartPoint = new PointF();
private PointF mMiddlePoint = new PointF();
private PointF mStartDragPoint = new PointF();
private PointF mMovePoint = new PointF();

private float oldDist = 1f;
private float scale;
private float oldEventX = 0;
private float oldEventY = 0;
private float oldStartPointX = 0;
private float oldStartPointY = 0;
private int mViewWidth = -1;
private int mViewHeight = -1;

private boolean mDraggable = false;


public CustomZoomView(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);

}

public CustomZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CustomZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    this.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.argb(100,255,255,255), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
}

@Override
public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mViewWidth = w;
    mViewHeight = h;
}

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap != null) {

        src = new Rect();
        src.left = 0;
        src.top = 0;
        src.right = bitmap.getWidth();
        src.bottom = bitmap.getHeight();
        mBitmap = bitmap;

        mBitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth() * 1;
        mBitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight() * 1;

        dst = new Rect();
        dst.left = (mViewWidth / 2) - (mBitmapWidth / 2);
        dst.top = (mViewHeight / 2) - (mBitmapHeight / 2);
        dst.right = (mViewWidth / 2) + (mBitmapWidth / 2);
        dst.bottom = (mViewHeight / 2) + (mBitmapHeight / 2);

    }
}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mStartPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mStartDragPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mTempDst.set(dst.left, dst.top, dst.right, dst.bottom);
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                midPoint(mMiddlePoint, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            if (mode == ZOOM) {
                mBitmapWidth = dst.right - dst.left;
                mBitmapHeight = dst.bottom - dst.top;
            }
            mode = NONE;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                mMovePoint.x = event.getX();
                mMovePoint.y = event.getY();
                drag(event);
            } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                zoom(event);
            } else if (mode == MOVE) {
                move(event);
            }
            break;
    }

    return false;
}

public void move(MotionEvent event) {

    int xChange = (int) (event.getX() - mStartPoint.x);
    int yChange = (int) (event.getY() - mStartPoint.y);

    dst.left = mTempDst.left + (xChange);
    dst.top = mTempDst.top + (yChange);

    dst.right = mTempDst.right + (xChange);
    dst.bottom = mTempDst.bottom + (yChange);

    invalidate();
}


public void drag(MotionEvent event) {

    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();
    float spacingX = eventX - mStartDragPoint.x;
    float spacingY = eventY - mStartDragPoint.y;
    float newPositionLeft = (dst.left < 0 ? spacingX : spacingX * -1) + dst.left;
    float newPositionRight = (spacingX) + dst.right;
    float newPositionTop = (dst.top < 0 ? spacingY : spacingY * -1) + dst.top;
    float newPositionBottom = (spacingY) + dst.bottom;
    boolean x = true;
    boolean y = true;

    if (newPositionRight < 0.0f || newPositionLeft > 0.0f) {
        if (newPositionRight < 0.0f && newPositionLeft > 0.0f) {
            x = false;
        } else {
            eventX = oldEventX;
            mStartDragPoint.x = oldStartPointX;
        }
    }
    if (newPositionBottom < 0.0f || newPositionTop > 0.0f) {
        if (newPositionBottom < 0.0f && newPositionTop > 0.0f) {
            y = false;
        } else {
            eventY = oldEventY;
            mStartDragPoint.y = oldStartPointY;
        }
    }

    if (mDraggable) {
        if (x) oldEventX = eventX;
        if (y) oldEventY = eventY;
        if (x) oldStartPointX = mStartDragPoint.x;
        if (y) oldStartPointY = mStartDragPoint.y;
    }

}

public void zoom(MotionEvent event) {
    float newDist = spacing(event);
    boolean in = newDist > oldDist;

    if (!in && scale < .01f) {
        return;
    }

    scale = newDist / oldDist;

    int xChange = (int) ((mBitmapWidth * scale) / 2);
    int yChange = (int) ((mBitmapHeight * scale) / 2);

    if (xChange > 10 && yChange > 10) { //ADDED THIS TO KEEP IT FROM GOING INVERSE

    int xMidPoint = ((dst.right - dst.left) / 2) + dst.left;
    int yMidPoint = ((dst.bottom - dst.top) / 2) + dst.top;

    dst.left = (int) (float) (xMidPoint - xChange);
    dst.top = (int) (float) (yMidPoint - yChange);

    dst.right = (int) (float) (xMidPoint + xChange);
    dst.bottom = (int) (float) (yMidPoint + yChange);

    }

    invalidate();

}


/**
 * Determine the space between the first two fingers
 */
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);

    return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/**
 * Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
 */
private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}


@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {


    if (mode == DRAG) {
        if ((mStartPoint.x > dst.left && mStartPoint.x < dst.right) && (mStartPoint.y < dst.bottom && mStartPoint.y > dst.top)
                && (mMovePoint.x > dst.left && mMovePoint.x < dst.right) && (mMovePoint.y < dst.bottom && mMovePoint.y > dst.top)) {
            mode = MOVE;
            v.vibrate(500);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (mode == MOVE) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, src, dst, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, src, dst, mPaint);
    } else {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, src, dst, null);
    }

}
}
```

...then add this to your activity

```
CustomZoomView customImageView = (CustomZoomView) findViewById(R.id.customZoomView);
customImageView.setBitmap(yourBitmap);
```

...and this in your view in xml.

```
<your.package.name.CustomZoomView
   android:id="@+id/customZoomView"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:longClickable="true"/>
```

...and add this to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution, it is based on @alexbirkett's solution.

```
public class ZoomImageView extends ImageView {

// region . Static fields .

static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
static final int CLICK = 3;

// endregion . Static fields .

// region . Fields .

private int mode = NONE;

private Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();

private PointF mLastTouch = new PointF();
private PointF mStartTouch = new PointF();
private float minScale = 0.5f;
private float maxScale = 4f;
private float[] mCriticPoints;

private float mScale = 1f;
private float mRight;
private float mBottom;
private float mOriginalBitmapWidth;
private float mOriginalBitmapHeight;

private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

//endregion . Fields .

// region . Ctor .
public ZoomImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public ZoomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public ZoomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}

// endregion . Ctor .

// region . Overrider .

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int bmHeight = getBmHeight();
    int bmWidth = getBmWidth();

    float width = getMeasuredWidth();
    float height = getMeasuredHeight();
    float scale = 1;

    // If image is bigger then display fit it to screen.
    if (width < bmWidth || height < bmHeight) {
        scale = width > height ? height / bmHeight : width / bmWidth;
    }

    mMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    mScale = 1f;

    mOriginalBitmapWidth = scale * bmWidth;
    mOriginalBitmapHeight = scale * bmHeight;

    // Center the image
    float redundantYSpace = (height - mOriginalBitmapHeight);
    float redundantXSpace = (width - mOriginalBitmapWidth);

    mMatrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace / 2, redundantYSpace / 2);

    setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    mMatrix.getValues(mCriticPoints);
    float translateX = mCriticPoints[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float trnslateY = mCriticPoints[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
    PointF currentPoint = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        //when one finger is touching
        //set the mode to DRAG
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mLastTouch.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mStartTouch.set(mLastTouch);
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        //when two fingers are touching
        //set the mode to ZOOM
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            mLastTouch.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mStartTouch.set(mLastTouch);
            mode = ZOOM;
            break;
        //when a finger moves
        //If mode is applicable move image
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            //if the mode is ZOOM or
            //if the mode is DRAG and already zoomed
            if (mode == ZOOM || (mode == DRAG && mScale > minScale)) {

                // region . Move  image.

                float deltaX = currentPoint.x - mLastTouch.x;// x difference
                float deltaY = currentPoint.y - mLastTouch.y;// y difference
                float scaleWidth = Math.round(mOriginalBitmapWidth * mScale);// width after applying current scale
                float scaleHeight = Math.round(mOriginalBitmapHeight * mScale);// height after applying current scale

                // Move image to lef or right if its width is bigger than display width
                if (scaleWidth > getWidth()) {
                    if (translateX + deltaX > 0) {
                        deltaX = -translateX;
                    } else if (translateX + deltaX < -mRight) {
                        deltaX = -(translateX + mRight);
                    }
                } else {
                    deltaX = 0;
                }
                // Move image to up or bottom if its height is bigger than display height
                if (scaleHeight > getHeight()) {
                    if (trnslateY + deltaY > 0) {
                        deltaY = -trnslateY;
                    } else if (trnslateY + deltaY < -mBottom) {
                        deltaY = -(trnslateY + mBottom);
                    }
                } else {
                    deltaY = 0;
                }

                //move the image with the matrix
                mMatrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                //set the last touch location to the current
                mLastTouch.set(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);

                // endregion . Move image .
            }
            break;
        //first finger is lifted
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(currentPoint.x - mStartTouch.x);
            int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(currentPoint.y - mStartTouch.y);
            if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                performClick();
            break;
        // second finger is lifted
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            break;
    }
    setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

//endregion . Overrides .

// region . Privates .

private void init(Context context) {
    super.setClickable(true);
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    mCriticPoints = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
}

private int getBmWidth() {
    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
    if (drawable != null) {
        return drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    }
    return 0;
}

private int getBmHeight() {
    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
    if (drawable != null) {
        return drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    }
    return 0;
}

//endregion . Privates .

// region . Internal classes .

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        float newScale = mScale * scaleFactor;
        if (newScale < maxScale && newScale > minScale) {
            mScale = newScale;
            float width = getWidth();
            float height = getHeight();
            mRight = (mOriginalBitmapWidth * mScale) - width;
            mBottom = (mOriginalBitmapHeight * mScale) - height;

            float scaledBitmapWidth = mOriginalBitmapWidth * mScale;
            float scaledBitmapHeight = mOriginalBitmapHeight * mScale;

            if (scaledBitmapWidth <= width || scaledBitmapHeight <= height) {
                mMatrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
            } else {
                mMatrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

// endregion . Internal classes .
}
```

Comment: If this doesn't work try extending android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me how to use that in Main Class?
I came up with this, Can you tell me what should be the next?

    ZoomableImageView touch =(ZoomableImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);

Answer (score 2):

Method to call the About&support dialog

```
 public void setupAboutSupport() {

    try {

        // The About&Support AlertDialog is active
        activeAboutSupport=true;

        View messageView;
        int orientation=this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        // Inflate the about message contents
        messageView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.about_support, null, false);

        ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.MyCustomTheme_AlertDialog1);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.action_aboutSupport);
        builder.setView(messageView);

        TouchImageView imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) messageView.findViewById(R.id.action_infolinks_about_support);
        imgDisplay.setMaxZoom(3f);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.myinfolinks_about_support);

        int imageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        int newWidth;

        // Calculate the new About_Support image width
        if(orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ) {
            // For 7" up to 10" tablets
            //if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
            if (SingletonMyInfoLinks.isTablet) {
                    // newWidth = widthScreen - (two borders of about_support layout and 20% of width Screen)
                newWidth = widthScreen - ((2 * toPixels(8)) + (int)(widthScreen*0.2));
            } else newWidth = widthScreen - ((2 * toPixels(8)) + (int)(widthScreen*0.1));

        } else {
            // For 7" up to 10" tablets
            //if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
            if (SingletonMyInfoLinks.isTablet) {
                newWidth = widthScreen - ((2 * toPixels(8)) + (int)(widthScreen*0.5));

            } else newWidth = widthScreen - ((2 * toPixels(8)) + (int)(widthScreen*0.3));
        }

        // Get the scale factor
        float scaleFactor = (float)newWidth/(float)imageWidth;
        // Calculate the new About_Support image height
        int newHeight = (int)(imageHeight * scaleFactor);
        // Set the new bitmap corresponding the adjusted About_Support image
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);

        // Rescale the image
        imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        dialogAboutSupport = builder.show();

        TextView textViewVersion = (TextView) dialogAboutSupport.findViewById(R.id.action_strVersion);
        textViewVersion.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.aboutSupport_text1)+" <b>"+versionName+"</b>"));

        TextView textViewDeveloperName = (TextView) dialogAboutSupport.findViewById(R.id.action_strDeveloperName);
        textViewDeveloperName.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.aboutSupport_text2)+" <b>"+SingletonMyInfoLinks.developerName+"</b>"));

        TextView textViewSupportEmail = (TextView) dialogAboutSupport.findViewById(R.id.action_strSupportEmail);
        textViewSupportEmail.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.aboutSupport_text3)+" "+SingletonMyInfoLinks.developerEmail));

        TextView textViewCompanyName = (TextView) dialogAboutSupport.findViewById(R.id.action_strCompanyName);
        textViewCompanyName.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.aboutSupport_text4)+" "+SingletonMyInfoLinks.companyName));

        Button btnOk = (Button) dialogAboutSupport.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);

        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialogAboutSupport.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialogAboutSupport.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
                // the About & Support AlertDialog is closed
                activeAboutSupport=false;
            }
        });

        dialogAboutSupport.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(SingletonMyInfoLinks.atualBackgroundColor));

        /* Effect that image appear slower */
        // Only the fade_in matters
        AlphaAnimation fade_out = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
        AlphaAnimation fade_in = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        AlphaAnimation a = false ? fade_out : fade_in;

        a.setDuration(2000); // 2 sec
        a.setFillAfter(true); // Maintain the visibility at the end of animation
        // Animation start
        ImageView img = (ImageView) messageView.findViewById(R.id.action_infolinks_about_support);
        img.startAnimation(a);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log.e(SingletonMyInfoLinks.appNameText +"-" +  getLocalClassName() + ": ", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change **ACTION_MOVE_EVENT** in **Chirag Raval** Answer **to set ZOOM_IN LIMIT**

```
float[] values = new float[9]; matrix.getValues(values);
                //0.37047964 is limit for zoom in
                if(values[Matrix.MSCALE_X]>0.37047964) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                }else if (scale>1){
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a bit late for this answer, but I hope it helps someone.

I was looking for the same thing (Zoom using pinch, and dragging image) and I found [this Android Developers Blog link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html).

Works perfect. No artifacts or what so ever. It uses `ScaleGestureDetector`.

Answer (score 0):

ZoomLib Link: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B34PUThnUsjVaHpkaGk0Z1hSRU0

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.dummy_layout_for_zooming);// Activity layout 
mZoomLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mZoomLinearLayout);// LinearLayout inside Activity layout
View v = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.layout_for_zoom, null, false);// View wants to zoom
v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
ZoomView zoomView = new ZoomView(this);// intialize lib
zoomView.addView(v);
mZoomLinearLayout.addView(zoomView);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think why you want to zoom-in and zoom-out the image **view** is because your image view is small and zooming in the image there will not let the image come out of the image view. Instead, image starts disappearing from the boundaries while zooming in. So letting the image come out of the image while we zoom in is what you want I guess.

So there are two tricks (according to me) to achieve this-

1. Change the layout params of the image view to cover the whole outermost view or view group at runtime while we are about to zoom-in the image.
2. Make an expanded Image view or Full Image View (height and width = Outermost View or View Group) in xml file and set it's visibility to gone. When we are about to zoom-in the image, load the image from small Image View into full Img View, map the image in fullImgView to image in smallImgView and make it's view visible.

Trick no.1 does not work when the image View is nested very much inside other views (like in nested recycler view)

Trick no.**2** works **always** :-)

Here is the implementation of trick no.2 -

```
public class ZoomOnTouchListener extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    private boolean isfullImgViewActive = false;
    // above boolean gets true when when we firstly move 2 fingers on the smallImgView and in this case smallImgView gets invisible and fullImgView gets visible
    // and false if smallImgView is visible and fullImgView is gone

    private float[] matrixArray = new float[9];
    private float orgScale;

    private PointF start = new PointF();
    private PointF prevP1 = new PointF();
    private PointF prevP2 = new PointF();
    private PointF mid = new PointF();
    private float oldDist = 1f;

    private ImageView mfullImgView;
    private ImageView smallImgView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mfullImgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView2);
        mfullImgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        smallImgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        smallImgView.setOnTouchListener(this);    

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //Log.i("0", "OnTouch()");
        if(v instanceof ImageView) {
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) v;

            boolean isImgViewSmall = (imgView == smallImgView);

            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only

                    //Log.i("T", "Motion Event: ACTION_DOWN");

                    if(isImgViewSmall)
                        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());

                    prevP1.set(event.getX(), event.getY());

                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: //second finger and other fingers down

                    prevP1.set(event.getX(0), event.getY(0));
                    prevP2.set(event.getX(1), event.getY(1));

                    oldDist = spacing(event);

                    midPoint(mid, event);

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:   //it doesn't mean fingers are moved. In this case, all pointers which are active are batched together
                                                // this case occurs after action_down or action_pointer_down

                    //Log.i("Tag", event.getX()+","+event.getY());
                    if(event.getPointerCount() == 2) {

                        PointF newMid = new PointF();
                        midPoint(newMid,event);

                        float newDist = spacing(event);

                        float scale = newDist/oldDist;

                        if( !isfullImgViewActive){   // is smallImgView is visible and mfullImgView is gone
                            Log.i("tag", "true");

                            isfullImgViewActive = true;

                            matrix.set(imgView.getImageMatrix());   //note:- do not write matrix = imgView.getImageMatrix() because it gives the smallImgView's matrix reference to the matrix variable and changes on matrix will reflect on smallImgView
                            matrix.getValues(matrixArray);

                            orgScale = matrixArray[0];

                            smallImgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            mfullImgView.setImageDrawable(smallImgView.getDrawable());
                            mfullImgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

                            mfullImgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            //To map the image of mFullImgView to that of smallImgView we have to 
                            // translate the mFullImgView's image
                            matrix.postTranslate(tx, ty);
                            /////////////NOTE///////////////
                            //here (tx,ty) are coordinates of top-left corner of smallimgView and 
                            // they MUST be relative to the origin of Outermost view or view group 
                            // where fullImgView is placed. So find tx,ty in your case by yourself

                            mfullImgView.setImageMatrix(matrix);      
                        }

                        if(isImgViewSmall) {
                            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x + tx, mid.y + ty);
                        }
                        else{
                            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                        }
                        oldDist = newDist;

                        matrix.postTranslate(newMid.x - mid.x, newMid.y - mid.y);

                        matrix.getValues(matrixArray);

                        mid.set(newMid);


                        prevP1.set(event.getX(0), event.getY(0));
                        prevP2.set(event.getX(1), event.getY(1));

                    }

                    else if(event.getPointerCount() == 1 ){

                        if(isfullImgViewActive) {

                            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - prevP1.x, event.getY() - prevP1.y);
                            matrix.getValues(matrixArray);
                        }

                        prevP1.set(event.getX(0), event.getY(0));

                    }

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

                    //Now if pointer of index 0 is lifted then pointer of index 1 will get index 0;
                    if(event.getActionIndex() == 0 && isfullImgViewActive){
                        Log.i("TAg", event.getActionIndex()+"");
                        prevP1.set(prevP2);
                    }

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted or all fingers are lifted

                    if(isImgViewSmall && !isfullImgViewActive) {

                        imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(event.getX() - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(event.getY() - start.y);
                        if (xDiff == 0 && yDiff == 0) {
                            imgView.performClick();
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    if(isfullImgViewActive){
                        if(matrixArray[0] <= orgScale){  //matrixArray[0] is Scale.X value

                            mfullImgView.setOnTouchListener(null);
                            mfullImgView.setImageDrawable(null);
                            mfullImgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            smallImgView.setOnTouchListener(this);
                            smallImgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                            smallImgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            isfullImgViewActive = false;

                        }
                        else if(matrixArray[0] > orgScale && isImgViewSmall){  //if the imgView was smallImgView

                            smallImgView.setOnTouchListener(null);
                            smallImgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                            smallImgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  // or View.INVISIBLE

                            mfullImgView.setOnTouchListener(this);
                        }
                    }

                    return true;


            }
            //end of Switch statement


            if(isfullImgViewActive) {   //active means visible
                mfullImgView.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen
            }

            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }
        else
            return false;
    }


    private float spacing(MotionEvent event)
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }


    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event)
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

}
```

NOTE:- Don't set OnClickListener to mfullImgView before setting onTouchListener to it. Setting that will let the fullImageView(if it is visible) steal the touch event of putting second finger down after lifting it for the first time because we want to let the smallImgView take all the touch events until all the fingers are lifted up for the first time.

Answer (score -2):

I am Using this one it is working perfectly.

```
<your.packagename.MyZoomableImageViewTouch
        android:id="@+id/mediaImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"/>
```

My a MyZoomableImageViewTouch class is below:

```
public class MyZoomableImageViewTouch extends ImageViewTouch
{

    static final float SCROLL_DELTA_THRESHOLD = 1.0f;

    public MyZoomableImageViewTouch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyZoomableImageViewTouch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyZoomableImageViewTouch(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (getScale() > 1f) {
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                } else {
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        setOnTouchListener(listener);
        setDisplayType(DisplayType.FIT_TO_SCREEN);
    }

    @Override
    protected float onDoubleTapPost(float scale, float maxZoom) {
        if (scale != 1f) {
            mDoubleTapDirection = 1;
            return 1f;
        }
        if (mDoubleTapDirection == 1) {
            mDoubleTapDirection = -1;
            if ((scale + (mScaleFactor * 2)) <= maxZoom) {
                return scale + mScaleFactor;
            } else {
                mDoubleTapDirection = -1;
                return maxZoom;
            }
        } else {
            mDoubleTapDirection = 1;
            return 1f;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScroll(int direction) {
        RectF bitmapRect = getBitmapRect();
        updateRect(bitmapRect, mScrollRect);
        Rect imageViewRect = new Rect();
        getGlobalVisibleRect(imageViewRect);

        if (null == bitmapRect) {
            return false;
        }

        if (Math.abs(bitmapRect.right - imageViewRect.right) < SCROLL_DELTA_THRESHOLD) {
            if (direction < 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (Math.abs(bitmapRect.left - mScrollRect.left) < SCROLL_DELTA_THRESHOLD) {
            if (direction > 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
    {
        if (getScale() == 1f) return false;
        if (distanceX != 0 && !canScroll((int) -distanceX)) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            return false;
        } else {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            mUserScaled = true;
            scrollBy(-distanceX, -distanceY);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your example have incomplete code, so many errors and ImageViewTouch class missing.