# horizontally scrolling image with zooming effect

Tags: android

May anyone please help me for horizontally scrolling image view along with zoom in , zoom out effect. I was using Gallery for horizontally scrolling but unable to implement zooming with gallery. In web view zooming is there but how to use horizontally scrolling.

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) It show how to use horizontal list view with TextViews. You ca create custom layout with WebView instead of that. Hope this will give you a clue.

Comment: Thanks @Anuj...is there any  otherway to do this without using webview?in one of the article i have read that webview is not a good solution for this.....

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking out for a gallery view.Android default has a Galleryview.It has the horizontal scrolling and the image in the middle get zoomed..Hope this [link](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/05/gallery-view-android-developer-tutorial.html) will help you out.

Comment: Thanks @sreedev....my requirement is:--i have two image which will in full screen and i could horizontally scroll the image.i could also zoom each image.

Comment: I had don almost a same view once.But i dint scrolled the image.I gave animations to the imageview and the image view is a customized image view with pinch zoom and drag.this link will give you the customized imageview

Comment: Thanks @sreedev but i have tried all the link given by you but not working. Please help me..my requirement is:--i have two image which will in full screen and i could horizontally scroll the image.i could also zoom each image

Comment: @Sreedev R: Gallery is deprecated in API level 16. It also lacks view recycling and is overall a terrible widget to work with. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

use a ViewFlipper with ZOOMCONTROL

This will help :[zooming image in viewflipper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846914/zooming-image-in-viewflipper)