# Zoom in zoom out ImageView with LongClick handle

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have the ImageView witch we can Zoom in and zoom out. I want to handle the LongClick event on that ImageView. How can I do this. Is this possible?

Comment: check `setOnLongClickListener()`

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
    imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "image long clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            zoomOut()/zoomIn();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I already did this but every times control goes to the onTouchListener instead of onLongClickListener. Is there any Motioevent related to Long touch in onTouchListener??

Answer (score 0):

You can see the way to handle onLongClick of Nuno Goncalves for Image View. To zoom-in, zoom-out image view, you can see this link: [Android imageView Zoom-in and Zoom-Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out) to understand.

Hope it's clearly.