# Resize Imageview and fitXY

Tags: android

I am resizing an ImageView and auto fitting the image to it, I need this for zoom in and out for image, this is the way i wish to implement this because the image is already 2048x2048 and I cant re-size it. Bu the code only works once for some reason, second click does not do anything. If you have other ideas or suggestions I would love to hear them. Thank you.

```
ImageView map = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewMap);
Bitmap mapIm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.myMap);
map.setImageBitmap(mapIm); //first view

zoomIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


            map.getLayoutParams().height = counter*5000 ;
            map.getLayoutParams().width = counter*5000;

            BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(mapIm);
            map.setImageDrawable(bmd);
            bmd = null;

            counter++;

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For zooming your image view

```
imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

or you can try the following link hope it may help you

[zoomableimageview](https://github.com/laurencedawson/ZoomableImageView)

try this hope it may help you

[example zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out)

Comment: @user1891408 did you check the link

Comment: @user1891408 you need to get zoom..isn't

Comment: Yes, only zoom without pinch, I have 2 buttons, zoom in and out

Comment: @user1891408 check the link