# Zoom in ViewFlipper

Tags: android, zooming, viewflipper, pinchzoom

I'm trying to do pinchzoom like this: [zoom the imageview on the double click in viewflipper in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364674/zoom-the-imageview-on-the-double-click-in-viewflipper-in-android)

I tried to adapt that code to my project but it doesn't works...

My code here (what i'm doing wrong?)

Also, I have code for "showNext" and "showPrev" in onTouch event, maybe are incompatible?

```
public class PageActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener,, OnScaleGestureListener{


// Objetos del Layout, se asignarán los valores correspondientes en tiempo de ejecución.
private LinearLayout layMain;
private ViewFlipper vf;

//...

private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pageviewer);

    // Inicialización de variables y componentes del LinearLayout
    initialize();

    // Al principio se carga la primera página.
    loadPage(currPage);
}

private void initialize() {
    ...
    layMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pageviewerLayout);
    layMain.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this);


    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this.getBaseContext(), (OnScaleGestureListener) this);

    vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.vfBookPage);
    ...
}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    //Obtengo la acción realizada en el evento "onTouch".
    switch (arg1.getAction()){
    //Si sólo ha presionando la pantalla.
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
        // Guardo el valor de X cuando el usuario presiona la pantalla.
        downXValue = arg1.getX();

        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
        // Obtengo el valor de X cuando el usuario ya ha soltado el dedo de la pantalla.
        float currentX = arg1.getX(); 

        // Voy hacia atrás: El usuario a movido el dedo hacia la derecha.
        if (downXValue < currentX){
            currPage--;
            if(loadPage(currPage)){
                // Asigno la animación tipo "slide_right".
                vf.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right));
                // Y muestro la página anterior.
                vf.showPrevious();
            }
        }

        // Voy hacia adelante: El usuario a movido el dedo hacia la izquierda.
        if (downXValue > currentX){
            currPage++;
            if(loadPage(currPage)){
                // Asigno la animación tipo "slide_left".
                vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left));
                // Y muestro la siguiente página.
                vf.showNext();
            }
        }

        break;
    }
    }

    return true;
}


/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
 */
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener#onScale(android.view.ScaleGestureDetector)
 */
@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //HERE DOES NOTHING! :(
    vf.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_enter));

    return false;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener#onScaleBegin(android.view.ScaleGestureDetector)
 */
@Override
public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener#onScaleEnd(android.view.ScaleGestureDetector)
 */
@Override
public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your `onTouch( )` event will trigger before the other MotionEvent components.  Since you are returning true each time, it will tell the system that the touch event has been handled.  It won't pass it along to your other touch events such as your `ScaleGestureDetector`.  If you want to handle other touch events after, you would need to return false.

Comment: Thanks Jay, but didn't works, if I change the return statement in the onTouch method to false I loose the functionality inside the onTouch method. And also the zoom doesn't works too...