# Is it possible to do Ken burns effect on an ImageView with Glide library android?

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for loading Images. What I want to know is if it is possible to get a Ken burns effect going using that library? Maybe an easy and straightforward way to do it?

**Update**

how about creating a ken burns effect gif and loading as gif, do you think thats a good idea?

I know how to do this using some other libraries, like KenBurnsView etc, what I wanted to know was if its possible with Glide and if using Gif with glide is better or worse than creating my own custom animation and adding it as the animator to glide

Comment: Probably not easily or straightforward. It would require a zoom animation after the image has loaded.

Comment: @cricket_007 how about creating a ken burns effect gif and loading as gif, do you think thats a good idea?

Comment: That is one alternative, sure. You would have to first make that using some other software, though, and it would repeatedly loop like all GIFs do.

Comment: you can look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680066/implementation-of-kenburns-effect-on-android-with-dynamic-bitmaps-setting

Comment: @cricket_007 but is it a good idea, memory usage wise?

Comment: @KingofMasses I know how to do this using some other libraries, like KenBurnsView etc, what I wanted to know was if its possible with Glide and if using Gif with glide is better or worse than creating my own custom animation and adding it as the animator to glide

Comment: A Gif would require significantly less work IMO

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, but performance wise which is better though? because I don't want to face any out of memory issues

Comment: You are animating an image, so there shouldn't be an out of memory... The Gif will probably be larger than a raw image unless you do some file-compression, but not large enough to cause out of memory.