# Add limit to zoom-in and zoom-out in android

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

I have an imageview that can be zoomed. I have a code that works well, but my problem is that I want to add a limit for maximum and minimum zooming levels.

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class Reach extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{
    private static final String TAG = "Touch";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f,MAX_ZOOM = 1f;

// These matrices will be used to scale points of the image
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

// The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
PointF start = new PointF();
PointF mid = new PointF();
float oldDist = 1f;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reach_us);
    int currentAPIVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
    {

        // RUN THE CODE SPECIFIC TO THE API LEVELS ABOVE HONEYCOMB (API 11+)   
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    ImageView view=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.map);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.home: {
        this.finish();

        return true;
    }

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    float scale;

    dumpEvent(event);
    // Handle touch events here...

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) 
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
        Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
        mode = DRAG;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

        mode = NONE;
        Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

        oldDist = spacing(event);
        Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
        if (oldDist > 5f) {
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(mid, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
        }
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        if (mode == DRAG) 
        { 
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
        } 
        else if (mode == ZOOM) 
        { 
            // pinch zooming
            float newDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
            if (newDist > 5f) 
            {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                // zoom out
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

    return true; // indicate event was handled
}

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Method: spacing Parameters: MotionEvent Returns: float Description:
 * checks the spacing between the two fingers on touch
 * ----------------------------------------------------
 */

private float spacing(MotionEvent event) 
{
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
 * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
 * ------------------------------------------------------------
 */

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) 
{
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

/** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE","POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int action = event.getAction();
    int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) 
    {
        sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
        sb.append(")");
    }

    sb.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) 
    {
        sb.append("#").append(i);
        sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
        sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
        sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
        if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
    }

    sb.append("]");
    Log.d("Touch Events ---------", sb.toString());
}
}
```

I have seen lot of question & answers linked with this, but no one really helps me. Please give me a solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The code shows and even comments exactly where the zooming happens, so just check the current zoom against some max there and do whatever you want (disable, message...) if exceeded.

Comment: I cant figure out where is I need to change the above code...plz help me.

Comment: How about where it says "// pinch zooming" ...

Comment: please give me an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got a solution  for this. But its not seems to be perfect one. Just add the methods given below after the switch cases and just before the `view.setImageMatrix(matrix);`
here is the methods:

```
private void limitZoom(Matrix m) {

        float[] values = new float[9];
        m.getValues(values);
        float scaleX = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
        float scaleY = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];
        if(scaleX > MAX_ZOOM) {
            scaleX = MAX_ZOOM;
        } else if(scaleX < MIN_ZOOM) {
            scaleX = MIN_ZOOM;
        }

        if(scaleY > MAX_ZOOM) {
            scaleY = MAX_ZOOM;
        } else if(scaleY < MIN_ZOOM) {
            scaleY = MIN_ZOOM;
        }

        values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] = scaleX;
        values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y] = scaleY; 
        m.setValues(values);
    }

    private void limitDrag(Matrix m) {
        float[] values = new float[9];
        m.getValues(values);
        float transX = values[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float transY = values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
        float scaleX = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
        float scaleY = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

        ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.map);
        Rect bounds = iv.getDrawable().getBounds();
        int viewWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int viewHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        int width = bounds.right - bounds.left;
        int height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;

        float minX = (-width + 20) * scaleX; 
        float minY = (-height + 20) * scaleY;

        if(transX > (viewWidth - 20)) {
            transX = viewWidth - 20;
        } else if(transX < minX) {
            transX = minX;
        }

        if(transY > (viewHeight - 80)) {
            transY = viewHeight - 80;
        } else if(transY < minY) {
            transY = minY;
        }

        values[Matrix.MTRANS_X] = transX;
        values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] = transY; 
        m.setValues(values);

    }
```

Is there is any other solution better than this one?

Comment: Alex Chengalan  can u please help me how to write code for zoom in and out on button click

Answer (score 1):

setOnTouchListener on your imageview

```
imgView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out)!This works for zoomIn and ZoomOut
change only **MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE** to set zoomIn Limit

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    float scale;
switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){


case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

            oldDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
            if (oldDist > 5f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
            }
            break;
// and in  your Action_Move Event
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            if (mode == DRAG)
            {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
                view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            }
            else if (mode == ZOOM)
            {
                // pinch zooming
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                if (newDist > 5f)
                {

                    scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                    //if scale is greater then 1 then its mean user want to 
                   //  zoom image
                  //0.37047964 is the limit of zoomin
                    float[] values = new float[9]; matrix.getValues(values);
                    if(values[Matrix.MSCALE_X]>0.37047964) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                    }else if (scale>1){
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                    }

                }
            }
            break;

   }
}
```