# does universal-image-loader have zoom in/out option?

Tags: android, image, zooming, pinch, universal-image-loader

I am applying costras universal-image-loader in my app.
however, I can't seem to find the pinch to zoom option anywhere.
Does it include it ?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of an ImageView, use the PhotoView library.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: danny, i check the git, but had some difficulty merging the too. Have you tried that yourself ?

Comment: Yeah I tried it and worked for me. You just need the attacher to your ImageView. See https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/blob/master/sample/src/uk/co/senab/photoview/sample/SimpleSampleActivity.java.

Comment: danny, I used ImageViewTouch , have you ever used it ?https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom/tree/master/ImageViewTouch

Comment: @tony9099  can u help me how to display more than one image with ImageTouchView i have successfully implemented for a single image but if i want to display more than one image then what should i need to do ?

Answer (score 2):

An issue regarding zoom was raised in the link below.

UIL doesn't provide any ImageView zoom functionality.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/66.

For zooming images

[Android imageView Zoom-in and Zoom-Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out)

[How can I get zoom functionality for images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images)

Comment: Raghunandan, has anybody added this to the Android-Universal-Image-Loader ?

Comment: I have not come across any till now. You can click on listview image show it in another activity (detailview) and apply zoom in and zoom out on the image.