# how to apply zoom in/out functionality for Image view on button click?

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I have to create one android application that shows the images from the server. I want to apply zoom effects on button click. I have two buttons one for zoom in and another is form zoom out. I want to apply zoom in or out on click of related button click. I searched a lot but did not find any thing related to my specific case. I have so far  implemented `imageview.onTouchlisterner()` for zoom effects but I don't want this I want to do zoom on button click so please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

a very simple technique that i used for such purpose, make a webview and load you image using its url into that webview on image clicked like this:

```
WebView web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
    mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait!", "Loading image and zoom controlls...");
    web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String url=getIntent().getExtras().getString("imageURL");

             web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            // when finish loading page
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if(mProgress.isShowing()) {
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
             web.loadUrl(url);

}
```

Comment: thank you for your replay @Saad Khokhar but i only want it for image view i don't want to use any other control

Comment: you will have to use any other controll to get what you want, this is easiest possible solution

Comment: ofcorse there are other ways out,
look into these links
[link](http://vinnysoft.blogspot.com/2009/08/zooming-imageview.html)
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out)