# Android file execute

Tags: android, file

I am doing an Android file explorer. How can I execute a file?
For example : "/xxx/xxx/image.jpg"
I need to display the image in the default android system image viewer when the user clicks on the name of the file.

Comment: You need to send an Intent. I think that this answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17831722/4568679

Answer (score 1):

You can use an intent to do that.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
//Action View to see an image in default native app in your device.
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//The path to see your image.
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + "/sdcard/test.jpg"), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about the code itself you can try with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + "your_image_path.jpg"), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

[ACTION_VIEW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) as per Android Documentation:

> Display the data to the user. This is the most common action performed
>   on data -- it is the generic action you can use on a piece of data to
>   get the most reasonable thing to occur.