# Code to load images

Tags: android, image, url, zooming

I need a code for load images with ALL this options:

**- High resolution images**

**- Pinch and double tap to zoom**

**- Load from URL**

**- ViewPager**

Anyone know a code like this?

Comment: What did you do so far? Where did you stop while working on your code? Have you already searched for that? If so, what did you get?

Comment: I get codes with any options... But I want all options

Comment: If you have code for those options, just put the pieces together and when you face one issue ask here with a specific question and not a general "give me the code"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use this library https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

1. High resolution images - yes it can load them
2. Pinch and double tap to zoom - No. but you can download the image with library and than write small code which will zoom it. Like this: [Android imageView Zoom-in and Zoom-Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out)
3. Load from URL - yes it can do it quick and also will cash downloaded image.
4. ViewPager - yes it can do it, you can find an example with ViewPager in Image Loader examples.

So 3 from 4, but zooming is too separate thing in order to be included to library which downloading images.

Comment: I use UIL. But it has 2 problems: 1 - the images has not quality with zoom. 2 - Viewpager with zoom is very bad

Comment: I didn't use UIL, so it is difficult for me to compare, but I think that quality of zoom will depends of quality of the image you will download. I also think that if you use huge resolutions and need really strong zoom you should look for OpenGL solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you for Image Loading from url as below:

I can recommend a different way that works like a charm: Android Query.

You can download that JAR file from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list)

```
AQuery androidAQuery = new AQuery(this);
```

As an example:

```
androidAQuery.id(YOUR IMAGEVIEW).image(YOUR IMAGE TO LOAD, true, true, getDeviceWidth(), ANY DEFAULT IMAGE YOU WANT TO SHOW);
```

It's very fast and accurate, and using this you can find many more features like animation when loading, getting a bitmap (if needed), etc.

Comment: You must need to do it programatically and indivisually, you will not get this kind of any library.