# Android Zoom in and zoom out the image in ImageView

Tags: android, zooming

Am creating an Android quiz application in which a question type will be picture base question, as shown in the image below.i took four  imageviews as shown in image   and showing the images from server in imageviews .So my question here is. on clicking on each of the image the image have to zoom and again on click it should zoom out,can anyone help me in doing so.
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

**Try this custom ImageView,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class GestureImageView extends ImageView {

    public static final String GLOBAL_NS = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
    public static final String LOCAL_NS = "http://schemas.polites.com/android";

    private final Semaphore drawLock = new Semaphore(0);
    private Animator animator;

    private Drawable drawable;

    private float x = 0, y = 0;

    private boolean layout = false;

    private float scaleAdjust = 1.0f;
    private float startingScale = -1.0f;

    private float scale = 1.0f;
    private float maxScale = 5.0f;
    private float minScale = 0.75f;
    private float fitScaleHorizontal = 1.0f;
    private float fitScaleVertical = 1.0f;
    private float rotation = 0.0f;

    private float centerX;
    private float centerY;

    private Float startX, startY;

    private int hWidth;
    private int hHeight;

    private int resId = -1;
    private boolean recycle = false;
    private boolean strict = false;

    private int displayHeight;
    private int displayWidth;

    private int alpha = 255;
    private ColorFilter colorFilter;

    private int deviceOrientation = -1;
    private int imageOrientation;

    private GestureImageViewListener gestureImageViewListener;
    private GestureImageViewTouchListener gestureImageViewTouchListener;

    private OnTouchListener customOnTouchListener;
    private OnClickListener onClickListener;

    public GestureImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        this(context, attrs);
    }

    public GestureImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        String scaleType = attrs.getAttributeValue(GLOBAL_NS, "scaleType");

        if (scaleType == null || scaleType.trim().length() == 0) {
            setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        }

        String strStartX = attrs.getAttributeValue(LOCAL_NS, "start-x");
        String strStartY = attrs.getAttributeValue(LOCAL_NS, "start-y");

        if (strStartX != null && strStartX.trim().length() > 0) {
            startX = Float.parseFloat(strStartX);
        }

        if (strStartY != null && strStartY.trim().length() > 0) {
            startY = Float.parseFloat(strStartY);
        }

        setStartingScale(attrs.getAttributeFloatValue(LOCAL_NS, "start-scale", startingScale));
        setMinScale(attrs.getAttributeFloatValue(LOCAL_NS, "min-scale", minScale));
        setMaxScale(attrs.getAttributeFloatValue(LOCAL_NS, "max-scale", maxScale));
        setStrict(attrs.getAttributeBooleanValue(LOCAL_NS, "strict", strict));
        setRecycle(attrs.getAttributeBooleanValue(LOCAL_NS, "recycle", recycle));

        initImage();
    }

    public GestureImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        initImage();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        if (drawable != null) {
            int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                displayHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

                if (getLayoutParams().width == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
                    float ratio = (float) getImageWidth() / (float) getImageHeight();
                    displayWidth = Math.round((float) displayHeight * ratio);
                } else {
                    displayWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                }
            } else {
                displayWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                if (getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
                    float ratio = (float) getImageHeight() / (float) getImageWidth();
                    displayHeight = Math.round((float) displayWidth * ratio);
                } else {
                    displayHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
                }
            }
        } else {
            displayHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            displayWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(displayWidth, displayHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        if (changed || !layout) {
            setupCanvas(displayWidth, displayHeight, getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);
        }
    }

    protected void setupCanvas(int measuredWidth, int measuredHeight, int orientation) {

        if (deviceOrientation != orientation) {
            layout = false;
            deviceOrientation = orientation;
        }

        if (drawable != null && !layout) {
            int imageWidth = getImageWidth();
            int imageHeight = getImageHeight();

            hWidth = Math.round(((float) imageWidth / 2.0f));
            hHeight = Math.round(((float) imageHeight / 2.0f));

            measuredWidth -= (getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight());
            measuredHeight -= (getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom());

            computeCropScale(imageWidth, imageHeight, measuredWidth, measuredHeight);

            if (startingScale <= 0.0f) {
                computeStartingScale(imageWidth, imageHeight, measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
            }

            scaleAdjust = startingScale;

            this.centerX = (float) measuredWidth / 2.0f;
            this.centerY = (float) measuredHeight / 2.0f;

            if (startX == null) {
                x = centerX;
            } else {
                x = startX;
            }

            if (startY == null) {
                y = centerY;
            } else {
                y = startY;
            }

            gestureImageViewTouchListener = new GestureImageViewTouchListener(this, measuredWidth, measuredHeight);

            if (isLandscape()) {
                gestureImageViewTouchListener.setMinScale(minScale * fitScaleHorizontal);
            } else {
                gestureImageViewTouchListener.setMinScale(minScale * fitScaleVertical);
            }

            gestureImageViewTouchListener.setMaxScale(maxScale * startingScale);

            gestureImageViewTouchListener.setFitScaleHorizontal(fitScaleHorizontal);
            gestureImageViewTouchListener.setFitScaleVertical(fitScaleVertical);
            gestureImageViewTouchListener.setCanvasWidth(measuredWidth);
            gestureImageViewTouchListener.setCanvasHeight(measuredHeight);
            gestureImageViewTouchListener.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

            drawable.setBounds(-hWidth, -hHeight, hWidth, hHeight);

            super.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (customOnTouchListener != null) {
                        customOnTouchListener.onTouch(v, event);
                    }
                    return gestureImageViewTouchListener.onTouch(v, event);
                }
            });

            layout = true;
        }
    }

    protected void computeCropScale(int imageWidth, int imageHeight, int measuredWidth, int measuredHeight) {
        fitScaleHorizontal = (float) measuredWidth / (float) imageWidth;
        fitScaleVertical = (float) measuredHeight / (float) imageHeight;
    }

    protected void computeStartingScale(int imageWidth, int imageHeight, int measuredWidth, int measuredHeight) {
        switch (getScaleType()) {
        case CENTER:
            // Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling.
            startingScale = 1.0f;
            break;

        case CENTER_CROP:
            startingScale = Math.max((float) measuredHeight / (float) imageHeight, (float) measuredWidth / (float) imageWidth);
            break;

        case CENTER_INSIDE:
            if (isLandscape()) {
                startingScale = fitScaleHorizontal;
            } else {
                startingScale = fitScaleVertical;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    protected boolean isRecycled() {
        if (drawable != null && drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
            if (bitmap != null) {
                return bitmap.isRecycled();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void recycle() {
        if (recycle && drawable != null && drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
            if (bitmap != null) {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (layout) {
            if (drawable != null && !isRecycled()) {
                canvas.save();

                float adjustedScale = scale * scaleAdjust;

                canvas.translate(x, y);

                if (rotation != 0.0f) {
                    canvas.rotate(rotation);
                }

                if (adjustedScale != 1.0f) {
                    canvas.scale(adjustedScale, adjustedScale);
                }

                drawable.draw(canvas);

                canvas.restore();
            }

            if (drawLock.availablePermits() <= 0) {
                drawLock.release();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Waits for a draw
     * 
     * @param max
     *            time to wait for draw (ms)
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public boolean waitForDraw(long timeout) throws InterruptedException {
        return drawLock.tryAcquire(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        animator = new Animator(this, "GestureImageViewAnimator");
        animator.start();

        if (resId >= 0 && drawable == null) {
            setImageResource(resId);
        }

        super.onAttachedToWindow();
    }

    public void animationStart(Animation animation) {
        if (animator != null) {
            animator.play(animation);
        }
    }

    public void animationStop() {
        if (animator != null) {
            animator.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        if (animator != null) {
            animator.finish();
        }
        if (recycle && drawable != null && !isRecycled()) {
            recycle();
            drawable = null;
        }
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    protected void initImage() {
        if (this.drawable != null) {
            this.drawable.setAlpha(alpha);
            this.drawable.setFilterBitmap(true);
            if (colorFilter != null) {
                this.drawable.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
            }
        }

        if (!layout) {
            requestLayout();
            redraw();
        }
    }

    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap image) {
        this.drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), image);
        initImage();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        this.drawable = drawable;
        initImage();
    }

    public void setImageResource(int id) {
        if (this.drawable != null) {
            this.recycle();
        }
        if (id >= 0) {
            this.resId = id;
            setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(id));
        }
    }

    public int getScaledWidth() {
        return Math.round(getImageWidth() * getScale());
    }

    public int getScaledHeight() {
        return Math.round(getImageHeight() * getScale());
    }

    public int getImageWidth() {
        if (drawable != null) {
            return drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int getImageHeight() {
        if (drawable != null) {
            return drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void moveBy(float x, float y) {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
    }

    public void setPosition(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void redraw() {
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public void setMinScale(float min) {
        this.minScale = min;
        if (gestureImageViewTouchListener != null) {
            gestureImageViewTouchListener.setMinScale(min * fitScaleHorizontal);
        }
    }

    public void setMaxScale(float max) {
        this.maxScale = max;
        if (gestureImageViewTouchListener != null) {
            gestureImageViewTouchListener.setMaxScale(max * startingScale);
        }
    }

    public void setScale(float scale) {
        scaleAdjust = scale;
    }

    public float getScale() {
        return scaleAdjust;
    }

    public float getImageX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float getImageY() {
        return y;
    }

    public boolean isStrict() {
        return strict;
    }

    public void setStrict(boolean strict) {
        this.strict = strict;
    }

    public boolean isRecycle() {
        return recycle;
    }

    public void setRecycle(boolean recycle) {
        this.recycle = recycle;
    }

    public void reset() {
        x = centerX;
        y = centerY;
        scaleAdjust = startingScale;
        if (gestureImageViewTouchListener != null) {
            gestureImageViewTouchListener.reset();
        }
        redraw();
    }

    public void setRotation(float rotation) {
        this.rotation = rotation;
    }

    public void setGestureImageViewListener(GestureImageViewListener pinchImageViewListener) {
        this.gestureImageViewListener = pinchImageViewListener;
    }

    public GestureImageViewListener getGestureImageViewListener() {
        return gestureImageViewListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable() {
        return drawable;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        this.alpha = alpha;
        if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.setAlpha(alpha);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        this.colorFilter = cf;
        if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.setColorFilter(cf);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageURI(Uri mUri) {
        if ("content".equals(mUri.getScheme())) {
            try {
                String[] orientationColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION };

                Cursor cur = getContext().getContentResolver().query(mUri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);

                if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    imageOrientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
                }

                InputStream in = null;

                try {
                    in = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri);
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

                    if (imageOrientation != 0) {
                        Matrix m = new Matrix();
                        m.postRotate(imageOrientation);
                        Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), m, true);
                        bmp.recycle();
                        setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), rotated));
                    } else {
                        setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp));
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (in != null) {
                        in.close();
                    }

                    if (cur != null) {
                        cur.close();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("GestureImageView", "Unable to open content: " + mUri, e);
            }
        } else {
            setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(mUri.toString()));
        }

        if (drawable == null) {
            Log.e("GestureImageView", "resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: " + mUri);
            // Don't try again.
            mUri = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Matrix getImageMatrix() {
        if (strict) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
        }
        return super.getImageMatrix();
    }

    @Override
    public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
        if (scaleType == ScaleType.CENTER || scaleType == ScaleType.CENTER_CROP || scaleType == ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE) {

            super.setScaleType(scaleType);
        } else if (strict) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable dr) {
        if (strict) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
        }
        super.invalidateDrawable(dr);
    }

    @Override
    public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        if (strict) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
        }
        return super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdjustViewBounds(boolean adjustViewBounds) {
        if (strict) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
        }
        super.setAdjustViewBounds(adjustViewBounds);
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageLevel(int level) {
        if (strict) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
        }
        super.setImageLevel(level);
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
        if (strict) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageState(int[] state, boolean merge) {
        if (strict) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        if (strict) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
        }
        super.setSelected(selected);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener l) {
        this.customOnTouchListener = l;
    }

    public float getCenterX() {
        return centerX;
    }

    public float getCenterY() {
        return centerY;
    }

    public boolean isLandscape() {
        return getImageWidth() >= getImageHeight();
    }

    public boolean isPortrait() {
        return getImageWidth() <= getImageHeight();
    }

    public void setStartingScale(float startingScale) {
        this.startingScale = startingScale;
    }

    public void setStartingPosition(float x, float y) {
        this.startX = x;
        this.startY = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
        this.onClickListener = l;

        if (gestureImageViewTouchListener != null) {
            gestureImageViewTouchListener.setOnClickListener(l);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the image dimensions are aligned with the orientation of
     * the device.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isOrientationAligned() {
        if (deviceOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            return isLandscape();
        } else if (deviceOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            return isPortrait();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int getDeviceOrientation() {
        return deviceOrientation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi friend This is your answer.

1 . Add Imageview to your layout

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
```

1. Add following code to java file

   ```
   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_0);
   imageView.setTag(R.drawable.sample_0);
   imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
           int id = (Integer) arg0.getTag();
           zoomImageFromThumb(arg0, id);
       }
   });
   ```
2. Add this method to your class.

   ```
   private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, int imageResId) {
   if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
       mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
   }

   final ImageView expandedImageView = (ImageView) ((Activity) mContext) .findViewById(R.id.expanded_image);
   expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId);
   final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
   final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
   final Point globalOffset = new Point();
   thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
   ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.container) .getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
   startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
   finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
   float startScale;
   if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height() > (float) startBounds
           .width() / startBounds.height()) {
       startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
       float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
       float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
       startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
       startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
   } else {
       // Extend start bounds vertically
       startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
       float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
       float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
       startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
       startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
   }
   thumbView.setAlpha(0f);
   expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
   expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);
   AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
   set.play(
           ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X,
                   startBounds.left, finalBounds.left))
           .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y,
                   startBounds.top, finalBounds.top))
           .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X,
                   startScale, 1f))
           .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y,
                   startScale, 1f));
   set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
   set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
   set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
       @Override
       public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
           mCurrentAnimator = null;
       }

       @Override
       public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
           mCurrentAnimator = null;
       }
   });
   set.start();
   mCurrentAnimator = set;
   final float startScaleFinal = startScale;
   expandedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
               mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
           }

           AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
           set.play(
                   ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X,
                           startBounds.left))
                   .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y,
                           startBounds.top))
                   .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView,
                           View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal))
                   .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView,
                           View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));
           set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
           set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
           set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
               @Override
               public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                   thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                   expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   mCurrentAnimator = null;
               }

               @Override
               public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                   thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                   expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   mCurrentAnimator = null;
               }
           });
           set.start();
           mCurrentAnimator = set;
       }
   });
   ```

   }