# Get position respect the loaded image in a zoomed imageview

Tags: android, image, imageview, zooming

I am using the class ZoomableImageView (here described [[Android imageView Zoom-in and Zoom-Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out][1]) by Nicolas Tyler)

On OnTouch event I would like to be able to get the position of the touch in pixel respect to the loaded image coordination system.

Comment: use ImageView.getImageMatrix()

Comment: https://github.com/Sivitas/TouchImageView good tutorial