# zoom scale in android imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview, zooming

The below code is tried so far...i have two image view ,one is zooming and another one is static image view

```
image.setOnTouchImageViewListener(new OnTouchImageViewListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMove() {


                PointF point = image.getScrollPosition();
                RectF rect = image.getZoomedRect();
                float currentZoom = image.getCurrentZoom();
                boolean isZoomed = image.isZoomed();
                scrollPositionTextView.setText("x: " + df.format(point.x)
                        + " y: " + df.format(point.y));
                zoomedRectTextView.setText("left: " + df.format(rect.left)
                        + " top: " + df.format(rect.top) + "\nright: "
                        + df.format(rect.right) + " bottom: "
                        + df.format(rect.bottom));
                currentZoomTextView.setText("getCurrentZoom(): " + currentZoom
                        + " isZoomed(): " + isZoomed);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.setMargins(Math.round(left-currentZoom*rect.left*250), Math.round(top-currentZoom*rect.left*30),
                        Math.round(rect.right), Math.round(rect.bottom));
                img.setLayoutParams(params);
                if(point.x>0.5)
                {
                    params.setMargins(Math.round(left-currentZoom*rect.left*250), Math.round(top-currentZoom*rect.left*30),
                            Math.round(rect.right), Math.round(rect.bottom));
                    img.setLayoutParams(params);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Imageview 1: zooming, ImageView 2: static image.. when image 1 zooms , the img 2 remains exact position ...say example cursor in human eye before zoom in and after zoom in it should maintains its same eye

Comment: and what is your question actually?

Comment: consider an example two imageview1 :1 st imageview is human face which has the pinch off zoom.       imageview 2 : 2 nd imageview is cursor which is static say(100*100). consider before zoom in it points in human eye....and after zoom in it should point same human eye. but it should not point the same that my problem

Comment: again, what is your question actually?

Comment: consider google map .....whenever the map get zoom in ....the mapmarker (red colour) remains its position ,the same sceneraio got it?

Comment: 1. make a custom ImageView, 2. override onDraw, 3. call super.onDraw, 4. then call getImageMatrix().mapPoints(pts); 5. pts[0] and pts[1] will then contain x and y position of the second Bitmap, 6. draw that Bitmap

Comment: did you get my sceneraio correctly?

Comment: 1) human face is my background imageview (has pinchzoom ) 2)cursor is static imageview 3) when i zoom the human face...cursor moves according to position(ie, it  cursor points human eye before zoom in and  remains its human eye position after zoom in )

Comment: yes i got it, implement 6 steps above

Comment: any code for implementing this task...moreover it should cope up with pinchzoom, dragging the imageview all those things...

Comment: if you are zooming/dragging your ImageView using ImageView#setImageMatrix() it will just work

Comment: i used touch imageview for pinch zoom functionality....can i use this or search for some other zooming options?

Comment: sure you can use  "touch imageview" in such case extend TouchImageView, not ImageView

Comment: public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {} this is actually touchimageview class did u mean this or some other?

Comment: getImageMatrix().mapPoints(pts) you means this code have the human eye position right? with these point we can fix the cursor exactly with human eye position while zoom in

Comment: yes input pts array should have x and y position of the eye

Comment: where i have to extend this touchimageview in main activity?

Comment: you dont know how to extend some class?

Comment: float[] myIntArray = {100,100};
   image.getImageMatrix().mapPoints(myIntArray); not able to get output values i.e(pts) sorry for making more trouble on you i'm just a beginner

Comment: whats myIntArray[0] and myIntArray[1] after calling mapPoints ? are you calling it in onDraw? Log.d these two floats and see the logcat

Comment: //set value to float array cursor image object (margin left (100) and margin right values(100))                                                                        float[] myIntArray = {100,100};//set marginleft values and right values to this where the cursor image located in human face image
getImageMatrix().mapPoints(myIntArray);
                                                                                                      Log.d("test", myIntArray[0]+"deemmo"+myIntArray[1]);
  //05-11 15:07:59.776: D/test(14542): myIntArray[0] -227.9169deemmo myIntArray[1]113.96624

Comment: see this snippet: http://pastebin.com/jTGapNQb

Comment: Thanks.  Dude....finally I made it... Keep supporting us..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same issue and I resolved it by implementing custom ImageView.

Custom ImageView:

```
public class ZoomableImageView extends ImageView
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    int mode = NONE;

    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 4f;
    float[] m;

    float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;
    float width, height;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight;

    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    Context context;

    public ZoomableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attr)
    {
        super(context, attr);
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                        last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = ZOOM;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == ZOOM || (mode == DRAG && saveScale > minScale))
                        {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                            float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                            if (scaleWidth < width)
                            {
                                deltaX = 0;
                                if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                    deltaY = -y;
                                else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                    deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                            }
                            else if (scaleHeight < height)
                            {
                                deltaY = 0;
                                if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                    deltaX = -x;
                                else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                    deltaX = -(x + right);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                    deltaX = -x;
                                else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                    deltaX = -(x + right);

                                if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                    deltaY = -y;
                                else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                    deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                            }
                            matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                }
                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true;
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)
    {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
        bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x)
    {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale)
            {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            }
            else if (saveScale < minScale)
            {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }
            right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
            bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
            if (origWidth * saveScale <= width || origHeight * saveScale <= height)
            {
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
                if (mScaleFactor < 1)
                {
                    matrix.getValues(m);
                    float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                    float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                    if (mScaleFactor < 1)
                    {
                        if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width)
                        {
                            if (y < -bottom)
                                matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                            else if (y > 0)
                                matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (x < -right)
                                matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                            else if (x > 0)
                                matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                    if (x < -right)
                        matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                    else if (x > 0)
                        matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    if (y < -bottom)
                        matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                    else if (y > 0)
                        matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        //Fit to screen.
        float scale;
        float scaleX =  width / bmWidth;
        float scaleY = height / bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        saveScale = 1f;

        // Center the image
        redundantYSpace = height - (scale * bmHeight) ;
        redundantXSpace = width - (scale * bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= 2;
        redundantXSpace /= 2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
}
```

And Use it in class like this

```
ZoomableImageView touch = (ZoomableImageView)findViewById(R.id.IMAGEID);
touch.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Add the view like this in XML:

```
<PACKAGE.ZoomableImageView
android:id="@+id/IMAGEID"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And I got solution from below link please refer it if you have any issue.

[Android imageView Zoom-in and Zoom-Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out)

Comment: according to your post you having an issue in zooming. Is it ?

Comment: actually my sceneraio is not problem in zooming concepts ....1) its google map( my imageview human face)....2) redmarker(my cursor)...

Comment: are using static google map that are you showing on imageView ?

Comment: 1) human face is my background   imageview  (has pinchzoom )                                                                           2)cursor is static imageview                                                                                      3) when i zoom the human face...cursor moves according to position(ie, it point human eye remains its human eye position after zoom in )

Comment: try this link may be it will help you. http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/face-detection-with-android-apis.html