# Check a view is visible to the screen

Tags: android, algorithm

I use ZoomableImageView at [Android imageView Zoom-in and Zoom-Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out) (See Nicolas Tyler's post)

I am using FrameLayout for overlap-view techniques. I want the ball (ImageView with id ball) to always overlap the (background) map (ZoomableImageView with id map).

The layout is like:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <mypackage.ZoomableImageView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@raw/gamemap"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ball"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@raw/ball"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

The ball is "attach" ("map to") to a (visible) point (for instance: PointF) on the gamemap. Like a map-application, when I zoom the background (gamemap), the ball needs to be automatically moved relative to the gamemap. So the ball would be visible or invisible to the screen when zooming.

I want to implement as I said. I want to check the ball is visible or invisible to the screen. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the visibility of any view like this.

```
if(tvEndDate.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
{

// do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply use

```
View.isShown()
```