# View of Endless Width and Height with Camera Operations .

Tags: android

How can We Create a Custom  View Like a MapFragment Where the Users can Scroll , Pinch ,Zoom in Zoom Out and do all the Camera Specific Operations. I would want the View to be of Endless width and Endless height, invisible at the beginning but rendered as the user Requests  by Navigating .  Is It Possible , if So , How ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tackling it the wrong way, the view itself is not endless- it's just the size of the screen, the data itself is "endless".
What you want to do is to create a view that response to gestures from the user and redraw itself depend on the position and the zoom level.
Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out)