# Android: make the size of a custom view bigger than the size of screen

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtDlq.png)I have a custom view and the user can draw rectangles(I used canvas). I would make the size of custom view bigger than the size of the screen. So, the user can draw not only in the size of screen. I tried ScrollView and NestedScrollView but they are not helpful to solve my problem.

Comment: What was wrong with ScrollView and NestedScrollView?

Comment: just use `View#scrollBy` / `View#scrollTo` methods

Comment: How use scrollBy and scrollTo?

Comment: with a `GestureDetector` for example

Comment: something like [this](http://pastebin.com/DE5PPmRc)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand from this question is you want to make a canvas where someone can draw some pictures. So you need a bigger canvas to that user can drag the positions to left-right, up and down. If I understood correctly, then I would say, you might think of a different work-around instead of looking for a view bigger than the screen size.

You can think of an simple `ImageView` which will be auto zoomed-in and if the user clicks twice it'll zoom-out. The user can drag the positions of the ImageView whenever he wants.

Here's an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6650484/3145960) about how you can implement the zoom in and out in an `ImageView`. Hope this will help to solve your problem.