# Get X/Y position of click inside ImageView

Tags: java, android, coordinates

I was searching for a way to display a very large scrollable image (3700x2400) at full size with ZoomIn/ZoomOut functionality.

The following question gave me a perfect solution:
[Android imageView Zoom-in and Zoom-Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out)

```
package com.oryx.hanenberg;

/**
 * Created by Jordy on 9-2-2017.
 */

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ZoomInZoomOut extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{
    private static final String TAG = "Touch";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f,MAX_ZOOM = 1f;

    // These matrices will be used to scale points of the image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    private ImageView imageView;
    private int fieldImgXY[] = new int[2];

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map);

        int[] posXY = new int[2];
        imageView.getLocationOnScreen(posXY);
        int x = posXY[0];
        int y = posXY[1];

        Log.d(TAG, TAG + " " + String.valueOf(x));
        Log.d(TAG, TAG + " " + String.valueOf(y));

        imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        float scale;

        dumpEvent(event);
        // Handle touch events here...

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
                mode = DRAG;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

                System.out.println(event.getX());
                System.out.println(event.getY());

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

                mode = NONE;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

                oldDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                if (oldDist > 5f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                if (mode == DRAG)
                {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
                }
                else if (mode == ZOOM)
                {
                    // pinch zooming
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                    if (newDist > 5f)
                    {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                        // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                        // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                        // zoom out
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

        return true; // indicate event was handled
    }

    /*
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Method: spacing Parameters: MotionEvent Returns: float Description:
     * checks the spacing between the two fingers on touch
     * ----------------------------------------------------
     */

    private float spacing(MotionEvent event)
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /*
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
     * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
     * ------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event)
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE","POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)
        {
            sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
            sb.append(")");
        }

        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++)
        {
            sb.append("#").append(i);
            sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
            sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
            sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
            if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";");
        }

        sb.append("]");
        Log.d("Touch Events ---------", sb.toString());
    }
}
```

activity_map.xml

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity = "center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bt_587f3ef7ccafa_bt_origineel"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

However, I want the touch events to register the X/Y-coordinates relative to the image. Now it's creating white space around the image when I'm zooming resulting false X/Y-coordinates. The X/Y-coordinates are also of the viewport, not of the entire content. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the top left corner of your Imageview as mentioned below:

```
int[] posXY = new int[2];
imageView.getLocationOnScreen(posXY);
```

With this and the touch coordinates you can calculate the point inside the ImageView as follows:

```
int touchX = (int) event.getX();
int touchY = (int) event.getY();

int imageX = touchX - posXY[0]; // posXY[0] is the X coordinate
int imageY = touchY - posXY[1]; // posXY[1] is the y coordinate
```

Comment: Hmmm I already tried this way but I still get only the X/Y-coordinates inside the viewport. The top left corner is also not 0 yet.

Comment: post the posXY values

Comment: cross check those values @Jordy

Comment: postxy[0]:0, postxy[1]: 96, the values stay the same no matter what.

Comment: Where is the image view kept in parent view

Comment: You mean the layout file where the ImageView is located?

Comment: The ImageView is inside a LinearLayout (the 2 only things inside the layout).Will edit the question with my view.

Comment: There might be some padding. Leave it , that wont be an issue for detecting your touch position in imageview

Comment: But the top left corner of the ImageView should be X:0, Y:0 right? 
Unfortunate this is not the case.