# How to implement a pinch-to-zoom feature on an ImageView?

Tags: android, pinchzoom

So I am trying to implement this little thing instagram-like.
Any idea in how can I do it?
I have a list view that uses a custom layout for displaying some posts in my app.

I want to be able to pinch photos in order to zoom simillar to the example below.
I am using the photo attacher to zoom currently, the problem is the photo can't exceed the initial size of the image View.

In example:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out have a look at this.

Comment: hello dear , u can find this answer then tell me plz..coz i want stuck this task

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend this library:

[PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)

You just have to create an attacher and "attach" it to your ImageView.

```
// Attach it like the following......after getting your image
PhotoViewAttacher yourAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(yourImageView);
```

Comment: that is the one I am using and thanks for answering. It works to some extent, the image gets zoomed in. However, the effect I am trying to achieve is that instead of zooming the image and keeping the imageView the same width/height I would like to increase the size of the imageView. Try to pinch a photo to zoom in on instagram, the photo gets bigger until it covers the entire screen.