# Android image full screen viewer

Tags: android

I'm new to android.What is the easiest way to pop an imageview to full screen (with pinch zoom enabled),when it is tapped, just like whatsapp images? I'm loading my images in a recycler view via Glide. Thank you for your time and reply.

Comment: Can you please tell me. what you want in detail?

Comment: You can use `ViewPager` to slide the image when get fullscreen and make your class to override the touch listener for `Pinch`.              Please see also this link [https://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I used PhotoView (https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) and Glide (https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

I created full screen activity first and put PhotoView in layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".PhotoviewerActivity">

    <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Then, I pass image URL that I want to show to the full screen activity and load image with Glide like below.

```
val imageUrl = intent.getStringExtra(IMAGE_URL)
Glide.with(applicationContext).load(imageUrl).into(fullscreen_content)
```

You can remove all not needed code from full screen layout and also disable from full screen activity code.
These codes are written in Kotlin.

Answer (score 12):

There is a library called [StfalconImageViewer](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/StfalconImageViewer/). It supports transition animation for image opening and closing, pinch-to-zoom and swipe-to-dismiss gestures out of the box. Using Glide it'll be done like this:

```
new StfalconImageViewer.Builder<>(context, images, new ImageLoader<String>() {
            @Override
            public void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String imageUrl) {
                Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(imageView)
            }
        }).show();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You are able to use `ImageView` view with scale type is `FIT_XY`(see more about scale type of `ImageView` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html))

To zoom an image you can use a third lib such as [this one](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom) or write a class by yourself(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out))

Comment: Will the imageview be in real 'full screen' or within the container? I want real full screen view with zooming ability.Thank you

Comment: It's up to you. Per item of the `RecyclerView` can be `ImageView` or `ViewGroup`(LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.) which contains the `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code for me for a single image and using glide Finally I found something similar to WhatsApp. I was digging over the internet for three days now I found a solution.

```
new StfalconImageViewer.Builder<String>(context, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(messageModel.get(position).getUrl().trim())), new ImageLoader<String>() {
    @Override
    public void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String image) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(image)
                .into(imageView);
    }
}).show();
```