# Zoom In Zoom Out ImageView Android Studio

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

I'm trying to implement zoom in and zoom out in my `imageView`. This code works with no error, but I think the Image **should not go less than 100% of its original size**.

How to fix it? Anyone, please help me, thank you.

[image: click here to see screenshot]

(the image too small)

This is my [literature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6650484/9117332) : (thank you for this answer)

```
public class ProfilePhotoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private ImageView profilePhoto;
    private String photoURL, name;

    private static final String TAG = "Touch";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f,MAX_ZOOM = 1f;

    // These matrices will be used to scale points of the image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_photo);

        Intent intentGet =getIntent();
        photoURL = intentGet.getStringExtra("PhotoURL");
        name = intentGet.getStringExtra("Name");

        setTitle(name);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.black)));

        //load profile image
        profilePhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.largeProfilePhoto);
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(photoURL)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_person)
                .into(profilePhoto);

        profilePhoto.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                super.onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        float scale;

        dumpEvent(event);
        // Handle touch events here...

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
                mode = DRAG;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

                mode = NONE;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

                oldDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                if (oldDist > 5f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                if (mode == DRAG)
                {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
                }
                else if (mode == ZOOM)
                {
                    // pinch zooming
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                    if (newDist > 5f)
                    {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                        // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                        // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                        // zoom out
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

        return true; // indicate event was handled
    }

    /*
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Method: spacing Parameters: MotionEvent Returns: float Description:
     * checks the spacing between the two fingers on touch
     * ----------------------------------------------------
     */

    private float spacing(MotionEvent event)
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /*
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
     * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
     * ------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event)
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE","POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)
        {
            sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
            sb.append(")");
        }

        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++)
        {
            sb.append("#").append(i);
            sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
            sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
            sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
            if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";");
        }

        sb.append("]");
        Log.d("Touch Events ---------", sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with this lib : [Subsampling Scale Image View](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=1509)

Comment: I think you can use scale gesture detector

Comment: use chrisbane's `PhotoView`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still can't resolve my problem
@Jaymin