# How i make movable perticuler dots on image with x y position in android?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I Have a image and i want to make a 8 dot on image, that dot are move when touch dot and drag to screen, is this possible to make that type of touch and movable dots on image?

Show above image on 8 point , i want to result like this image and also that point are move when you touch that point and move on image and also want that point x,y coordinate .

[image]

i tried below code but its show dots are not in proper form , and all dots move at the same time.

```
class DrawingView extends View {
        Bitmap bitmap;

        float x, y;

        public DrawingView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_dot);
        }


        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                }
                break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    x = (int) event.getX();
                    y = (int) event.getY();

                    invalidate();
                }

                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    x = (int) event.getX();
                    y = (int) event.getY();
                    System.out.println(".................." + x + "......" + y); //x= 345 y=530
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
           // canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, paint);  //originally bitmap draw at x=o and y=0
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x++, y++,  null);
            }
        }
    }
```

if anyone know about that type of view or any solution for it then help.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a custom `ImageView` which extends the `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView` class, which implements an `OnTouchListener` with an `ArrayList<Dot>` which will keep track of the `Dot`s.
2. You override `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` of the custom `ImageView` and iterate through the `ArrayList` of `Dot`s and draw each `Dot` in the list using `canvas.drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float radius, @NonNull Paint paint)`.
3. Whenever `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is fired you check if the touch was inside an existing dot.

   If it was you set that `Dot` to a global variable i.e. `touchedDot`, when the users moves `OnTouchListener` fires `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` which you then check if  `touchedDot != null` and if so simply change its `x` and `y` to match the events via `touchedDot.x = event.getX()` and `touchedDot.y = event.getY()` and then call `invalidate()` which will call the `ImageView`s `onDraw` method and the *dot* will be moved as the users finger moves. When the user lifts their finger either from a touch or a move, `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is fired, there you simply check if `touchedDot == null` and if so you then create a new `Dot` at the `x` and `y` they touched in, otherwise you set `touchedDot = null` to reset it for the next move or touch event.

Here is an example I created using [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) to load the image into the custom `ImageView`:

**build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**DrawableDotImageView.java:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DrawableDotImageView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final ArrayList<Dot> dots = new ArrayList<>();
    private Paint dotPaint;
    private Dot touchedDot;

    public DrawableDotImageView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        setup();
    }

    public DrawableDotImageView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup();
    }

    public DrawableDotImageView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        setOnTouchListener(this);
        dotPaint = new Paint();
        dotPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        dotPaint.setAlpha(100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        dots.forEach((dot) -> {
            canvas.drawCircle(dot.getX(), dot.getY(), dot.getRadius(), dotPaint);
            Log.d("ImageView", "Drawing X: " + dot.x + " Y: " + dot.y);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                dots.forEach((dot) -> {
                    if (dot.isInside(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                        touchedDot = dot;
                        Log.d("ImageView", "Dot touched");
                    }
                });
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (touchedDot != null) {
                    touchedDot.x = event.getX();
                    touchedDot.y = event.getY();
                    invalidate();
                    Log.d("ImageView", "Dot moving X: " + touchedDot.x + " Y: " + touchedDot.y);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (touchedDot != null) {
                    touchedDot = null;
                } else {
                    dots.add(new Dot(event.getX(), event.getY(), 35));
                    invalidate();
                    Log.d("ImageView", "Dot created X: " + event.getX() + " Y: " + event.getY());
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static class Dot {
        private float x;
        private float y;
        private final float radius;

        public Dot(float x, float y, float radius) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        public float getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public float getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public float getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        //https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-if-a-point-lies-inside-or-on-circle/
        public boolean isInside(float x, float y) {
            return (getX() - x) * (getX() - x) + (getY() - y) * (getY() - y) <= radius * radius;
        }
    }
}
```

**TestFrament.xml:** (change package name according to your own)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.myapplicationjava.DrawableDotImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**TestFrament.java:**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    DrawableDotImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Picasso.get().load("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d4/d8/a0/d4d8a016155f00165411066bb9a0ab42.jpg").into(imageView);
}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: i need Already added 8 dot on image view who's movable with image zoomin & zoomout . it possible?

Comment: 1. Thats pretty simple in the `setup()` method add your initial 8 dots to the `dots` `ArrayList`. 2. To zoom in and out please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6650484/1133011)

Comment: can you edit setup method? i didn't get what you say , and i want zoom view with this Drawable dot image view.

Comment: I'm sure you can edit it yourself and add 8 lines of `dots.add(new Dot(x, y, 35));` in `setup()` where x and y are your coordinates you want. As for the link, my answer extends the `ImageView` so any example using an `ImageView` will work for `DrawableDotImageView`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i want to this view with zoomin & zoomout image view can you please add this?

Comment: In this view dot is go out side of view so how i get event when dot move to out side of view?

Comment: Also need some text above the dot , i edited my question can you check please?

Comment: Sorry man I'm not here to do all your work for you unless you will be paying me. These are all really separate questions, some of which I have answered and you have shown no interest in attempting yourself. I won't be helping further I think I have given you a good enough foundation to take it from there.

Comment: Thanks @ David for your help , i am new in this field so lake of knowledge about that type  of custom class.

Comment: That's understandable but making no effort to understand will get you nowhere in this field. I wish you luck and hope you can attempt to read the code and understand and implement some of the ideas I have shown you.

Comment: Also please do mark this question as solved and then create new questions, one per issue on what you are having when trying to accomplish your tasks.